# assign func(const void *) to func(void *) in C

Tags: c, constants, function-pointers

I have a function that takes a function pointer and apply it over a list. It's prototype is as follows:

```
void applyList(List *, void applyFunc(void *));
```

Now I want to supply a function that prints the element in the list. Since I'm not modifying the list element, the print function looks like this:

```
void printNode(const void *nodeData){
    Data *dPtr=(Data*)nodeData;
    printf("%s", dPtr->str );
}

//Usage
applyList(list, printNode);
```

However I got an compiler error saying

```
expected ‘void (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(const void *)’
```

I don't want to add `const` to `apply`'s prototype, because I might supply some function that modifies the data. Any suggestion on how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, in C function pointers are not polymorphic. At all. Attempting to force a cast leads to undefined behavior.

Your only standard-conforming way out is to write a wrapper function:

```
static void wrap_printNode(void *nodeData) {
  printNode(nodeData);
}
```

Note, however, that your const is kind of useless here:

```
Data *dPtr=(Data*)nodeData;
```

You just casted away the const declaration. Try to keep it on there:

```
const Data *dPtr=(const Data*)nodeData;
```

Comment: Technically there is a very small and verbose degree of polymorphism (http://stackoverflow.com/a/559671/163349), but you are correct that not even `((void(*)(void*))void_from_void_const_ptr)(p)` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to add `const` to `apply`'s prototype, because I might supply some function that modifies the data.

Then there is no sane solution. The data isn't yours to modify, which is why it's marked `const`.