# Function pointer conversion in C

Tags: c, function, gcc, function-pointers

As I heard, It is not safe to convert pointer to function to `void*`.

Okay, is it safe to cast

`void (*enumerate) (void (*)(const struct foo *event, void *), void *)`

to

`void (*enumerate) (void (*)(const void *event, void *), void *)`

and then call it with

`void (*)(const void *, void *)` as first argument, which treats its first void* as struct foo*?

Comment: @rkosegi Casting a function pointer to `void*` is undefined behavior. There's no guarantee it'll fit. It might work though, if you're lucky.

Comment: IIRC, it's not just UB; it's plain forbidden, so a strict compiler would not accept a program that tries (`gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror` wouldn't).

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type?rq=1

Comment: I am not casting function ptr to void*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not safe. It's not guaranteed by the C standard that a `struct foo *` and a `void *` have the same size and format. In general, casting function pointers to other function pointer types is a recipe for disaster. The safe solution is to insert an extra function that converts the arguments to the right type, just as you'd do when writing a comparison function for `qsort` that handles non-`void *` arguments:

```
static int compare_foo_as_voidp(void const *a, void const *b)
{
    return compare_foo((struct foo const *)a, (struct foo const *)b);
}
```

(As Oli Charlesworth writes in the comment, the cast itself is not the problem, but calling through the pointer causes UB.)

Comment: +1.  However, casting between function pointer types is ok (although silly), so long as you never call the function from the wrong pointer type.

Comment: Can you give an example of a version of C which has two different pointer sizes?

Comment: @AaronDigulla - x86 DOS made use of [near and far pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_memory_model#Pointer%5Fsizes).

Comment: @AaronDigulla: On a Harvard architecture, code and data live in separate address spaces, so function pointers may well have a different size to object pointers.

Comment: @BrettHale: I know but I never wrote DOS code. Would the compiler throw an error when you tried to cast one into the other or just widen/shorten the pointer?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: when a function is called through a pointer of the wrong type, the compiler will not convert its arguments.

Comment: But it **is** guaranteed by the C Standard that any pointer to object can be assigned to a `void *` and back without loss of information.