# Are void* pointer and pointer to some structure (layout-) compatible?

Tags: c++, c

In other words, may I reinterpret (not convert!) `void*` pointer as a pointer to some structure type (assuming that the `void*` pointer really holds properly converted valid structure address)

Actually I'm interesting in the following scenario:

```
typedef struct void_struct void_struct_t;

typedef somestruct
{ 
    int member;
    // ... other members ...
}somestruct_t;

union 
{
    void*          pv; 
    void_struct_t* pvs; 
    somestruct_t*  ps; 
}u;

somestruct_t s={};

u.pv= &s;

u.ps->member=1; // (Case 1)  Ok? unspecified? UB? 

u.pvs=(void_struct_t*)&s;

u.ps->member=1;  // (Case 2) )Ok?
```

What I found in the C11 standard is rather dissapointing for the Case 1:

§6.2.5

> 28 A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
> pointer to a character type.[footnote: The same representation and alignment requirements
> are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from
> functions, and members of unions.] Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified
> versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment
> requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and
> alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same
> representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not
> have the same representation or alignment requirements.

It seems, though, that Case 2 is valid, but I'm not 100% sure...

The question is mostly C-oriented, but I'm interesting in C++ too (I'd want the code would be valid while compiling by C++ compiler). Honestly, I found even less in C++11 standard, so even Case 2 seems questionable for me... however, may be I'm missing something.

**[edit]
What is the real problem behind this question?**

I have a (potentially large) set of types defined as structs.
For each type I need to define a companion type:

```
typedef struct companion_for_sometype
{
  sometype* p_object;
  // there are also other members
}companion_for_sometype;
```

Obviously, the companion type would be a template in C++, but I need a solution for C
(more exactly, for "clean C", i.e for intersection of C89 and C++ as I want my code to be also valid C++ code).

Fortunately, it is not a problem even in C, since I can define a macro

```
DECLARE_COMPANION(type_name) typedef struct companion_for_##type_name
{
  type_name* p_object;
  // there are also other members
}companion_for_##type_name;
```

and just invoke it for every type that need a companion.

There is also a set of generic operations on companion types.
These operations are also defined by macros (since there are no overloads in pure C).

One of this operations, say

```
#define op(companion_type_object) blablabla
```

should assign a `void*` pointer to `p_object` field of the companion object,
i.e. should do something like this:

```
(companion_type_object).p_object= (type_name*) some_function_returning_pvoid(..)
```

But the macro doesn't know type_name (only an *object* of companion type is passed to the macro)
so the macro can't do the appropriate pointer cast.

The question is actually inspired by this problem.

To solve it, I decide to reinterpret target pointer in the assignment as void* and then assign to it.
It may be done by replacing the pointer in the companion declaration with a union of pointers
(the question is about this case), or one may reinterpret target pointer directly, say:

```
*(void**) &(companion_type_object).p_object= some_function_returning_pvoid(..)
```

But I can't find any solution without reinterpreting pointers (maybe I'm missing some possibilities though)

Comment: Even though if its technically UB, in practice Case 1 will most likely work on any compiler/system, unless the struct is polymorphic/uses inheritance.

Comment: @smerlin: I suspect that even for pointers to polymorphic structs it will most likely work for most compilers, but..

Comment: yeah, for most cases, but it will definitly not work for classes/structs using virtual multiple inheritance.

Comment: @user396672 - What are you trying to do? Perhaps we can answer how to do that?

Comment: C and C++ really differ on these things, so your C++ tag is probably misleading.

Comment: @Bo Persson: I've tried to explane the real problem (sorry if the explanation is too verbose).

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Indeed, I hesitated adding C++ tag, but I'm interesting  in C++ case too. Maybe add "clean-C" tag to SO for such cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`void *` is a pointer that can hold any object pointer type, that includes all pointers to structure type. So you can assign any pointer to a structure type to a `void *`.

But `void *` and pointers to structure types are not guaranteed to have the same representation so your case 1 is undefined behavior.

> (C11, 6.2.5p28) "[...] Pointers to other types need not have the same
>   representation or alignment requirements."

Comment: Are you consider Case 2 as valid?

Comment: What is `struct void_struct` ? You didn't declare the structure type in your example.

Comment: It is just a replacement for void.. I don't want even define it but it may be defined arbitrary if needed

Comment: void_struct_t* is just a work around possible UB with void* pointer. it is actually a placeholder for "pointer to any struct". I hope that its union with pointer to actual struct should work...

Comment: Case 2 is really equally undefined, because it writes to one union member and reads from another. The C++ standard says *"In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time."*. You can only read from the member that is currently stored in the union. Most compilers have an extension allowing this, but *the language* does not.

Comment: @BoPersson, there is no "*the language*" this is tagged C++ and C and they differ on that. C allows type puning through `union`s under most circumstances. In fact the primary use of `union`s in C is type puning.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `void *` automatically casts to any object type, so this will work:

```
(companion_type_object).p_object = some_function_returning_pvoid(..)
```

In C++, you need to use `static_cast`, but you can find out the required type using `decltype` :

```
(companion_type_object).p_object = 
    static_cast<decltype(*(companion_type_object).p_object) *>(
        some_function_returning_pvoid(..))
```

In C++03 you should be able to use some compiler extension equivalent to `decltype`.  Alternatively, you could provide a macro-generated method on `companion_type_object` to cast a `void *` to the appropriate type:

```
static type_name *void_p_to_object_p(void *p) { return static_cast<type_name *>(p); }
...
(companion_type_object).p_object = companion_type_object.void_p_to_object_p(
    some_function_returning_pvoid(..))
```

Comment: but C generates a warning while casting from void* (?)

Comment: It shouldn't; are you sure that `some_function_returning_pvoid` actually returns `void *`?

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what I really should do. I need a special macro, say, null_ptr_assign(type_p,void_p) and implement this macro for C++ and C in different manner (and, maybe differently for some C compilers that have decltype analog)

Comment: ... and null_ptr_assign(type_p,void_p) may be function template (not a macro) for C++ case (without decltype, so valid even for C++03). I regret I can't choose two answers as accepted (ouah's answer better matches the original question). I can only upvote, though your answer is what I really need.

Comment: @user396672 - Do not use void in the first place. The word void is a hint - void aka lack of space or volume.