# gcc: "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type"

Tags: c, gcc

I would like to remove the following warning from the code of an old library I am working on:

```
Image.c:171:22: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   image->f.get_pixel = get_pixel1;
```

I shortend the code in the following text to make it easier to read!

Now, I think get_pixel1 is a function pointer to this function:

```
#define READ_BIT(image, x, y)   \
    (image->data[(y * image->bytes_per_line) + (x >> 3) ] & (1 << (x & 7)))

static unsigned long
get_pixel1(XImage *image, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    return READ_BIT(image, x, y) != 0;
}
```

While f.get_pixel is defined in here:

```
typedef struct _XImage {
    int width, height;      /* size of image */
    /* snip */
    struct funcs {      /* image manipulation routines */
    struct _XImage *(*create_image)( /*snip*/ );
    /* snip */
    unsigned long (*get_pixel)  (struct _XImage *, int, int);
    /* snip */
    } f;
} XImage;
```

My question is what do I have to cast here to remove the warning in the question's title:

```
    image->f.get_pixel = (?????)get_pixel1;
```

Or is there something additional to do except the cast?

Comment: could be that your function pointer wants signed ints, while your function uses unsigned ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the struct you have:

```
unsigned long (*get_pixel)  (struct _XImage *, int, int);
```

You declared your function as:

```
static unsigned long
get_pixel1(XImage *image, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
```

The mismatch is the `unsigned` in the second and third parameters, either add them in the struct member or remove them from the function definition.

Also in general you should not cast a function pointer to a function pointer of another type as it results in undefined behavior.  So if you ever find yourself doing something like this:

```
image->f.get_pixel = (?????)get_pixel1;
```

There is probably a better solution.  See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type) for more detail.

Comment: I added unsigned and there is no more warning. Unsigned is right since there are no negative pixel positions on the screen. I would not have seen this flaw at all here, so thank you very much for this help!