# Casting function pointers

Tags: c, function-pointers, qsort

I am writing a function that receives a pointer to a comparison function and an array of `MyStructs` and is supposed to sort the array according to the comparison function:

```
void myStructSort(
                  struct MyStruct *arr,
                  int size,
                  int (*comp)(const struct MyStruct *, const struct MyStruct *)) {
  qsort(arr, size, sizeof(struct MyStruct), comp);
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't compile because `qsort` expects the comparator to receive `void *` arguments and not `const struct MyStruct *`. I thought of several bad solutions and was wondering what the correct solution is.

**Option 1**

Cast `comp` to `int (*)(const void *, const void*)`. This compiles but is undefined behavior (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type)).

**Option 2**

Create a global variable `int (*global_comp)(const struct MyStruct *, const struct MyStruct *)` and set `global_comp=comp` inside `myStructSort`. Then create a function:

```
int delegatingComp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  return globalComp((const struct MyStruct *)a, (const struct MyStruct *)b);
}
```

And in `myStructSort` call `qsort(arr, size, sizeof(struct MyStruct), delegatingComp)`. The problem with this is the icky global variable.

**Option 3**

Reimplement `qsort`. This is functionally safe but very bad practice.

Is there a magical perfect fourth option?

**Edit**

I can't change the API of `myStructSort` and I am compiling my code using `gcc c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wvla`.

Comment: In that case, a wrapper function like the one you came up with in option 2 is the best approach. Btw, tbh I didn't quite get the idea about global variables you mentioned. What are they for?

Comment: HighPredator@, `delegatingComp` needs to know which function to call and it can't be passed to it as an argument because it needs to match the argument of `qsort`.

Comment: if you are using `gcc`, gnu extension allows you to define a subfunction inside of a function. it simulates a stack based closure. if you don't mind portability damage, you can try that.

Comment: @BenjyKessler, ahh, now I get it.

Comment: qsort API is basically broken, there is no good solution for this problem.

Comment: @BenjyKessler looks like standard C99 is explicitly selected. You're out of luck.

Comment: @n.m. how broken is that? could you explain?

Comment: Is there a problem with converting the `const void *` parameters to whichever other pointer type is required? It's one line of code per comparator... I could think of faaaar more significant targets for optimisation.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr it won't work. Casting the function pointer is WAY more portable anyway.

Comment: @n.m. what do you mean `qsort` api is broken. i don't think casting will help if the api is broken.

Comment: @n.m. Casting the function pointer isn't portable, because `qsort` will end up calling the function as though it recieves `const void *` representation when that pointer representation may differ from the actual representation.

Comment: @n.m. I doubt undefined behaviour is all that portable. Sure, the random effects you get out of it may be the same, but I wouldn't call that "portable".

Comment: @Quentin This question is about optimising keystrokes, I gather, right?

Comment: @BenjyKessler Why do you think a global is necessary? Care to explain?

Comment: Well technically not global but static. But it can't be passed to `delegatingComp` as an argument.

Comment: @BenjyKessler Just one note which I'm not happy to convert to an answer, because I think this design is silly and don't approve of it, but suppose in your option 2 you use the first argument as a boolean; if it's non-null you perform a comparison (by calling the function) and if it's null you set the `static` variable to whatever is in the second argument (you can use `struct` or `union` to pass a function pointer)... This would allow you to move the *global* into the function (as a `static` variable), but I'm sure that's not what you want, and it's still bloody hideous!

Comment: Yeah, I thought of something like that but I figured that the code complexity will be higher in this implementation than just rewriting qsort so I discarded it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Option 2 breaks thread-safety, so I wouldn't choose that one.

Option 3 is just plain wrong as you point out. There is no reason to re-implement quicksort and potentially make a mistake.

Option 1 is UB but it will work on any sane compiler. If you choose this option be sure to add a comment.

I would also consider:

Option 4. Redesign the interface of `myStructSort` to take `int (*)(const void *, const void*)` or scrap it entirely and call `qsort` directly. Basically send it back to the architecht, because he made a poor design choice.

Comment: For option 2, you can put the 'global' in thread-local storage.

Comment: Nice overview of the available options! For me, this makes it pretty clear that the only actually sane option is Option 1, i.e. simply cast the function pointer. Everything else is a cure worse than the disease.

Answer (score 5):

following approach only works for `gcc`. It's a part of gnu extension. further please reference to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions

first let's make sure the prototype of `qsort` is in [such a form](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort):

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

then you can:

```
void myStructSort(
                  struct MyStruct *arr,
                  int size,
                  int (*comp)(const struct MyStruct *, const struct MyStruct *)) {
  int comparator(const void * a, const void *b) {
    return comp((const struct MyStruct *)a, (const struct MyStruct *)b);
  }
  qsort(arr, size, sizeof *arr, comparator);
}
```

But again, since it uses gnu extension, don't expect too much portability.

ABOUT YOUR COMMENT: for modern `gcc`, gnu standard is default instead of iso ones. specifically, lastest `gcc` should use `gnu11` standard. older ones are using `gnu89`. so, I don't know about your command line params, but if `-std` is not set, this will work.

following is an example taken from `info gcc`, just in case the link is dead. it shows a closure-like usage of nested function:

```
 bar (int *array, int offset, int size)
 {
   int access (int *array, int index)
     { return array[index + offset]; }
   int i;
   /* ... */
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     /* ... */ access (array, i) /* ... */
 }
```

Comment: No older ones use `gnu89` and not `gnu99`, they jumped directly from C89 to C11 for their default.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using gcc, then you can use the `qsort_r` function in glibc since 2.8, which allows you to specify a comparator function with an additional user-supplied argument:

```
void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
             int (*compar)(const void *, const void *, void *),
             void *arg);
```

This is not portable, of course, and it requires you to define the feature-test macro:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

(On FreeBSD -- and, presumably, Mac OS X -- there is a similar but incompatible `qsort_r`; the difference is that the user-supplied context argument is provided as the *first* argument to the comparison function, rather than the last argument.)

But if you have it, it allows you to avoid the global in option 2:

```
/* This struct avoids the issue of casting a function pointer to
 * a void*, which is not guaranteed to work. It might not be
 * necessary, but I know of no guarantees.
 */
typedef struct CompContainer {
   int (*comp_func)(const struct MyStruct *, const struct MyStruct *);
} CompContainer;

int delegatingComp(const void *a, const void *b, void* comp) {
  return ((CompContainer*)comp)->comp_func((const struct MyStruct *)a,
                                           (const struct MyStruct *)b);
}

void myStructSort(
              struct MyStruct *arr,
              int size,
              int (*comp_func)(const struct MyStruct *,
                               const struct MyStruct *)) {
  const CompContainer comp = {comp_func};
  qsort_r(arr, size, sizeof(struct MyStruct), delegatingComp, &comp);
}
```

([Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/M5F4Co))

Comment: I think you could do without the wrapper struct. A simple pointer-to-pointer-to-function would be good enough. It's a data pointer so it will survive a round trip through `void *`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: That's not guaranteed by the C standard, and I don't know if gcc guarantees it either.

Comment: @rici Both POSIX and Windows (which exhausts the set of ABIs you are liable to encounter in practice) do in fact guarantee that pointers to functions can be cast to `void *` and back without loss of information, in order not to have to have two variants of `dlsym` / `GetProcAddress` for object and function symbols.  Also, I believe Wumpus Q. Wumbley is correct: a pointer *to* a pointer to a function is a data pointer and therefore round-trippable through `void *` in standard C.

Comment: You are correct about @wumpus; I misread the comment and I apologize  for that. The struct adds no overhead, though. An actual pointer to the posix requirement would be helpful, but I can search it out when I get home.

Comment: @rici POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html : last paragraph of the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Comment: @rici Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx does not state this requirement explicitly, but it is implied by `GetProcAddress` being able to retrieve the address of a "function _or_ variable".  (Note that `FARPROC` is, iirc, a function pointer type.)

Comment: @zwol: That's a pretty well hidden requirement :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The correct approach is to cast from `void const *` to  `MyStruct const *` in the comparison function.

This is well-defined for the first object, because the pointer that was passed to the comparison function was created by a cast from `MyStruct const *` to `void const *`, and casting a pointer to `void` back to its original type is allowed (and it's really the only thing that is).

For the other array members, it is assumed that casting `void const *` to `char const *`, adding the offset of the object, generated by multiplying the object size with the position of the object in the array, and casting that back to `void const *` will give a pointer that can be cast back to `MyStruct const *`.

That is a bold assumption, but usually works out. There may be corner cases where this doesn't work, but in general compilers pad any `struct foo` to a multiple of its alignment to ensure that array members' start addresses have a distance of `sizeof(struct foo)`.

Casting function pointers is generally unsafe and needs to be avoided, as different data types may have different representations -- for example, a `void *` must be able to express every possible address as it could have been converted from a `char *`, while a `MyStruct *` is guaranteed to have a few of the least significant bits clear as any valid object would be aligned -- so it is entirely possible that the calling convention for these types could be different.

Answer (score 1):

The only sane option is to re-write the interface you've created, or make a new one.

[I've done something very similar with bubble sort on another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662383/sorting-structures-basis-of-any-structure-element).

In short, with C, you want your sort function to be of the form:

```
void* bubbleSort(void* arr, int (*compareFcn)(void*, void*),
    size_t sizeOfElement, size_t numElements)
```

And your comparison function to be of the form:

```
int compareFunction(void *a, void *b);
```