# Casting function pointers with different return types

Tags: c

This question is about using function pointers, which are not precisely compatible, but which I hope I can use nevertheless as long as my code relies only on the compatible parts. Let's start with some code to get the idea:

```
typedef void (*funcp)(int* val);

static void myFuncA(int* val) {
  *val *= 2;
  return;
}

static int myFuncB(int* val) {
  *val *= 2;
  return *val;
}

int main(void) {
  funcp f = NULL;
  int v = 2;

  f = myFuncA;
  f(&v);
  // now v is 4

  // explicit cast so the compiler will not complain
  f = (funcp)myFuncB;
  f(&v);
  // now v is 8

  return 0;
}
```

While the arguments of `myFuncA` and `myFuncB` are identical and fully compatible, the return values are not and are thus just ignored by the calling code. I [tried the above code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/816cf130ea0d6a81) and it works correctly using GCC.

What I learned so far from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942838/casting-function-pointers) is that the functions are incompatible by definition of the standard and **may** cause undefined behavior. My intuition, however, tells me that my code example will still work correctly, since it does not rely in any way on the incompatible parts (the return value). However, in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782166/function-pointers-with-different-return-types) a possible corruption of the stack has been mentioned.

So my question is: Is my example above valid C code so it will **always** work as intended (without any side effects), or does it depend on the compiler?

---

EDIT:
I want to do this in order to use a "more powerful" function with a "les powerful" interface. In my example `funcp` is the interface but I would like to provide additional functionality like `myFuncB` for optional use.

Comment: Why do you need to do these ugly things? Read this: [The XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: No, it will not work always, you are unlucky that it works with your setup. It is simply undefined, there is no guarantee that the compiler does not replace your call with anything completely different.

Comment: You can make a ---lambda--- function wrapper that will call the other function.

Comment: @user202729 - *Wrong Language*

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, I know this is not C++, so no lambda. But it's possible to write another function that call this function.

Comment: Don't do it. Recommended reading: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040119-00/?p=41003 That blog post shows how this can cause real crashes that are pretty hard to debug.

Comment: Or very short and simple reading [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.3 Pointers(p8)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8)

Comment: Why even bother to speculate about this? A `myFuncA` compatible wrapper for `myFuncB` is a one-liner and all problems are gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed it is undefined behaviour, don't do that!

Yes the code functions, i.e. it doesn't fall over, but the value you assign after returning void is undefined.

In a very old version of "C" the return type was unspecified and int and void functions could be 'safely' intermixed. The integer value being returned in the designated accumulator register. I remember writing code using this 'feature'!

For almost anything else you might return the results are likely to be fatal.

Going forward a few years, floating-point return values are often returned using the fp coprocessor (we are still in the 80s) register, so you can't mix int and float return types, because the state of the coprocessor would be confused if the caller does not strip off the value, or strips off a value that was never placed there and causes an fp exception. Worse, if you build with fp emulation, then the fp value may be returned on the stack as described next. Also on 32-bit builds it is possible to pass 64bit objects (on 16 bit builds you can have 32 bit objects) which would be returned either using multiple registers or on the stack. If they are on the stack and allocated the wrong size, then some local stomping will occur,

Now, c supports struct return types and return value copy optimisations. All bets are off if you don't match the types correctly.

Also some function models have the caller allocate stack space for the parameters for the call, but the function itself releases the stack. Disagreement between caller and implementation on on the number or types of parameters and return values would be fatal.

By default C function names are exported and linked undecorated -  just the function name defines the symbol, so different modules of your program could have different views about function signatures, which conflict when you link, and potentially generate very interesting runtime errors.

In c++ the function names are highly decorated primarily to allow overloading, but also it helps to avoid signature mismatches. This helps with keeping arguments in step, but actually, ( as noted by @Jens ) the return type is not encoded into the decorated name, primarily because the return type isn't used (wasn't, but I think occasionally can now influence) for overload resolution.

Comment: Your last para doesn't really help, here, because even in C++ the return type is not encoded within, so they also aren't able to avoid the problem that you describe.

Comment: That is true. It helps with arguments, but you are right it doesn't help with non-trivial return types.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is an undefined behaviour and you should never rely on undefined behaviour if want to write portable code.

Function with different return values can have different calling conventions. Your example will probably work for small return types, but when returning large structs (e.g. larger than 32 bits) some compilers will generate code where struct is returned in a temporary memory area which should be cleaned up the the caller.

Comment: *"if want to write portable code."* -> *"if want to write **working** code."*

Comment: I meant "working" as "guaranteed to be working". I don't consider "working by chance" to be "working".