# Is it acceptable to type-cast the return value of a C function?

Tags: c, casting

A colleague of mine claims that type-casting the return value of a function is undefined in C, however I cannot find anything to support his claim.

I know that type-casting a function pointer is bad, see here:
[Casting a function pointer to another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type)

But I want to confirm that the following code would be acceptable and well defined:

```
// Some function
int ret = foo(bar);

// Some variable with some different type
unsigned int a;

// Cast function result to match variable type
a = (unsigned int) foo(bar);
```

Comment: I can't imagine why your colleague believes this - it is most assuredly a feature of the `c` language.  It is a common (and required) functionality.

Comment: return value is just an rvalue

Comment: Any claim has to be supported by some evidence. Does your colleague have one? Otherwise it is called a "speculation".

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree completely! He had no evidence, but he is also an intelligent person, so I did not want to immediately discount his claim. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than what's answered in the comments, you can back your argument with some article like [this](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FLP07-C.+Cast+the+return+value+of+a+function+that+returns+a+floating-point+type), that repeatedly talks about casting return values.

One trivial example that we use every now and then is to cast the return value of the `round()` function.

This is so trivial that you can even see it mentioned in the [C Standard, page 567 of this pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=567).

> In the above conversions from floating to integer, the use of (cast)x
>   can be replaced with (cast)round(x), (cast)rint(x),
>   (cast)nearbyint(x), (cast)trunc(x), (cast)ceil(x), or (cast)floor(x)

Comment: Sure enough. Thanks for backing up your claims!