# Optimizing out helper functions

Tags: c, callback, language-lawyer, function-pointers

This is more or less a request for clarification on
[Casting a function pointer to another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type/561040#561040) with example code

```
struct my_struct;
void my_callback_function(struct my_struct* arg);
void do_stuff(void (*cb)(void*));

static void my_callback_helper(void* pv)
{
    my_callback_function(pv);
}
int main()
{
    do_stuff(&my_callback_helper);
}
```

The answer says a "good" compiler should be able to optimize out 
the `my_callback_helper()` function but I found no compiler at [https://gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/Km5nqy)
 that does it and the helper function gets always generated even if it's [just a jump to `my_callback_function()`](https://godbolt.org/g/Km5nqy) (-O3):

```
my_callback_helper:
        jmp     my_callback_function
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $my_callback_helper, %edi
        call    do_stuff
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

So my question is: Is there anything in the standard that prevents compilers from eliminating the helper?

Comment: In my experience, compilers tend to do a poor job at inlining function pointer calls even if the function pointer's value can be determined at compile-time. You could try to toss in the `inline` keyword. As far as I know, there is nothing in the standard preventing the optimization.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in the standard that directly prevents this optimization. But in practice, it's not always possible for compilers when they don't have a "full picture".

You have taken the address of `my_callback_helper`. So compiler can't easily optimize it out because it doesn't know what `do_stuff` does with it. In a separate module where `do_stuff` is defined, compiler doesn't know that it can simply use/call `my_callback_function` in place of its argument (`my_callback_helper`). In order to optimize out `my_callback_helper` completely, compiler has to know what `do_stuff` does as well. But `do_stuff` is an external function whose definition isn't available to compiler. So this sort of optimization may happen if you provide a definition for `do_stuff` and all its uses.

Comment: This should also be resloved by using link time optimization (-flto with GCC) during compile and "link" steps.

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps it's forbidden because of the possibility pointer comparison. `do_stuff()` might be trying to compare the received pointer to `my_callback_function()`. With the optimization on, the comparison will say `my_callback_function == my_callback_helper`, and it might not be legal for two different objects to have the same address. If it is illegal, then it's a little unfortunate the jump can't be eliminated. Maybe it'd be better for fn-casts to be implementation-defined rather than undefined.