# Pointers to functions casting

Tags: c, struct

I have the following structs:

```
struct mtmFlix_t {
    List usersList;
    List seriesList;
};

struct User_t {
    int age;
    char* username;
    MtmFlix mtmFlix;
};
```

These are the typedefs in list.h :

```
typedef void* ListElement;
typedef ListElement(*CopyListElement)(ListElement);
typedef void(*FreeListElement)(ListElement);
```

These are the typedefs in user.h and MtmFlix.h :

```
typedef struct User_t *User;
typedef struct mtmFlix_t* MtmFlix;
```

I would like to use the following function in mtmflixCreate, but I can't seem to figure out how to cast the `UserCreate` and `UserFree` to `(*void)` ?

```
List listCreate(CopyListElement copyElement, FreeListElement freeElement);

MtmFlix mtmFlixCreate()
{
    MtmFlix newMtmFlix = malloc(sizeof(*newMtmFlix));
    if (newMtmFlix == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    newMtmFlix->seriesList=listCreate(?????);
    newMtmFlix->usersList=listCreate(?????);
}
```

The following functions appear in user.h :

```
User UserCreate(MtmFlix mtmFlix, const char* username,int age);
Void UserFree(User user);
```

Comment: You'll have to match the types exactly or this won't work.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: C requires exact matches on the function signature, not "close enough". Your functions don't match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting a function pointer to another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type)

Comment: What is the `Void` typedef?

Comment: [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Comment: Am I missing the obvious, or does the code not show the definition of the type `List`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The code is List-less. ;-)

Comment: @Yasmin12 "can't seem to figure out how to cast the UserCreate and UserFree to (*void)" --> Do you mean to `void*`, a `void` pointer?  That is usually a weak approach as a function pointer may not fit in `void *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You have to create functions that have the needed types. Something like this:

```
ListElement CopyUserListElement(ListElement elem) {
    // (ListElement) is not necessary here, but included for completeness
    return (ListElement)CopyUser((User_t*)elem);
}

void FreeUserListElement(ListElement elem) {
    UserFree((User_t*)elem);
}
```