# Get incompatible-pointer-types warning except void *

Tags: c, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, void-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun1(int *c){return;}
void fun2(void *p){return;}
void fun3(void **p){return;}

typedef void (* myfunptr)(void *);

void fun4(myfunptr b){
return;
}

    int
    main(){
    
       int *p;
       void *q = p;
    
       fun1(p); //no warning
    
       fun1(q); //no warning
    
       fun2(p); //no warning
    
       fun2(q); //no warning
    
       fun3(&p); //warning - incompatible pointer types
    
       fun3(&q); //no warning
       
       fun4(fun1); //warning - incompatible pointer types
    
       fun4(fun2); //no warning 
    
       return 0;
    
    }
```

I am realizing warning at `fun3(&p)` as `void **` is not a generic pointer like `void *`. However, I'm a little puzzled why there is a warning in the case of `fun4(fun1)`, as `void *` and `int *` are implicitly converted without warning.

My next question is there a way I will get warnings of "incompatible types" for all  non-compatible pointer conversion except when `void *` or `void **` involved. Because using `-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types` disables warnings of all types of conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fun1(p); //no warning

`int*` is obviously compatible with `int*`

> fun1(q); //no warning

`void*`, as a special case type, is compatible with every other object pointer type and are implicitly converted to/from other pointers to object type.

> fun2(p); //no warning

As already mentioned, `void*` and `int*` can be implicitly converted to/from each other.

> fun2(q); //no warning

`void*` is obviously compatible with `void*`

> fun3(&p); //warning - incompatible pointer types

The special rule for `void*` does not apply "recursively". `void**` is not a generic object pointer type. It is not compatible with `int**`. You'll see some trashy APIs doing such conversions still (CUDA etc), but they are bad and relying on non-standard behavior.

> fun3(&q); //no warning

`void**` is obviously compatible with `void**`.

> fun4(fun1); //warning - incompatible pointer types

Function pointers need to point at identical functions to be compatible. Same return type, same parameters, same qualifiers.

> fun4(fun2); //no warning

You provide a function pointer of the expected type, so it is fine. Please note that `fun2` in this case "decays" from a function to a function pointer, since it is used in an expression.

---

Also please note that `void*` is the generic *object* pointer. You cannot use it as a generic pointer type to mix with function pointers!

Answer (score 2):

Although `int*` is implicitly convertible to `void*` (as you say, without warning), the case for your `fun4(fun1);` statement is rather different. In that case, you are implicitly converting a *function pointer* – between pointers to functions with **different signatures**.

A fuller discussion of compatibility between pointers to different types of function can be found here: [Casting a function pointer to another type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/559581/10871073).

Although, in your particular case, there *should* be no issues when calling `fun1` through the `fun4` pointer parameter (because, as you say, the former has an argument list compatible with that provided for the `fun4` parameter), the compiler is still (IMHO) 'justified' in providing you with a warning that the signature for `fun1` is different from that for the expected `myfunptr`.