# invalid conversion from 'void* (*)(int*)' to 'void* (*)(void*)'

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to calculate the multiple thread C++ program to compute the sum of the cubes of the N first integer numbers.

Each thread should compute a partial sum to divide the work among them evenly.
Struggling with pthread_create arguments it's giving error.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <pthread.h> 

#define n 6
#define p 4

using namespace std; 

int part = 0; 
int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
int sum[p]={0};
void* cube_array(int arr[]) 
{ 

    int thread_part = part++; 

    for (int i = thread_part * (n/ p); i < (thread_part + 1) * (n/ p); i++) {
        sum[thread_part] += arr[i]*arr[i]*arr[i]; 
        }

        return NULL;
} 

// Driver Code 
int main() 
{ 

    pthread_t threads[p]; 


    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) 
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, cube_array, (void*)NULL); 

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) 
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); 

    int total_sum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) 
        total_sum += sum[i]; 

    cout << "sum is " << total_sum << endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting a function pointer to another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is thread support in standard library since c++11 standard, so you can use `std::thread` instead using pthread. It have no problems with different thread function signatures, but has good support for any variants of functions you need.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <thread>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

#define n 6
#define p 4

using namespace std; 

int part = 0; 
int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
int sum[p]={0};
void cube_array(int arr[], int thread_part) 
{
    for (int i = (thread_part * n) / p; i < ((thread_part + 1) * n) / p); i++) {
        sum[thread_part] += arr[i]*arr[i]*arr[i]; 
        }
} 

// Driver Code 
int main() 
{ 

    std::deque<std::thread> threads; 


    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) 
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread(cube_array, arr, part++)); 

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) 
        threads[i].join(); 

    int total_sum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) 
        total_sum += sum[i]; 

    cout << "sum is " << total_sum << endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. It solved that but still my ans is not coming right. Is there something wrong with my logic.

Comment: @ShivamMishra the splitting with `(n/p)` is incorrect since it gives only one element per thread. You should use `thread_part*n/p` and `(thread_part+1)*n/p` (divide **after** the multiplication).

Comment: The `std::min(...)` is useless since the maximal value of `thread_part` is `p-1`, then `(thread_part+1)*n/p` won't exceed `n`.

Answer (score 5):

According to [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), the signature of **pthread_create()** is

```c
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

So functor that you pass should receive arg `void*` (now you are receiving `int*`).
So just change the arg type to `void*`, and cast it to `int*` inside the function, so it will look like this:

```c
void* cube_array(void* temp_arr) 
{ 
    int* arr = (int*)temp_arr;
    
    int thread_part = part++;
```

P.S. you should switch from pthread to [`std::thread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) or [`std::future`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/).

Comment: After doing it that it is showing error
invalid conversion from 'void* (*)(void**)' to 'void* (*)(void*)'

Comment: @ShivamMishra this ans2er is correct, so you must be doing something wrong when trying to apply it to your code, but we can't see what you tried.