Are there hidden dangers when using callbacks with member pointers?
In Arduino projects, I often find that I need to have some class call a callback function when something happens, for instance when a pin reaches a certain value, or when a certain amount of time has elapsed. I can't use the STL, so I've written a small class that lets me attach a static member function with a reference to the object it is a member of, which then calls the actual instanced callback. When I call the call() function, it executes the attached callbacks.
Here's the class:
class CallbackCaller
{
    public:
    using instance_pointer_t = void*;
    using instance_callback_t = void(*)(instance_pointer_t);

    private:
    instance_pointer_t instance;
    instance_callback_t instanceCallback;


    public:
    void attach(instance_callback_t callback, instance_pointer_t instance);
    void call();
};

instanceCallback will hold a pointer to a static function in the class. instance holds a pointer to the class instance that the method in instanceCallback is a (static) member of.
Here's the implementation:
#include "CallbackCaller.h"

void CallbackCaller::attach(instance_callback_t callback, instance_pointer_t instance)
{
    this->instanceCallback = callback;
    this->instance = instance;
}

void CallbackCaller::call()
{
    if (this->instanceCallback && this->instance)
    {
        this->instanceCallback(this->instance);
    }
}

I attach a callback function via attach(), passing a pointer to the static member function and a pointer to the class instance. When it's time to execute the callback, I call call().
The idea is that a class would use it like so:
class Test
{
    CallbackCaller callbackCaller;

    public:
    void actualMemberCallback()
    {
        Serial.println("Member callback called!");
    }

    static void staticCallback(Test instance)
    {
        instance.actualMemberCallback();
    }

    void begin()
    {
        // Attach the static "staticCallback" function, which will receive a pointer to this object's instance as an argument, which it can then use to call the instance's member function.
        this->callbackCaller.attach((CallbackCaller::instance_callback_t)staticCallback, (CallbackCaller::instance_pointer_t)this);    
    }

    void raiseCallback()
    {
        // In a real world scenario this function would be called when a certain condition is met that warrants the callback.
        this->callbackCaller.call();
    }
};

This appears to work as intended:
Test test;
test.begin();
test.raiseCallback();    

This will produce "Member callback called!" in the serial monitor.
However, function pointers, void pointers, and pointers in general can be tricky. I'm wondering if there's some sort of trap I'm walking into? Is this a valid way of calling member functions that won't lead to unforeseen consequences down the road?

Inside your begin function I think this->callbackCaller.begin should be this->callbackCaller.attach, can you please check?

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica You're right, classic copy/paste error. I edited the question, thanks!

This is a sound idea but a wrong implementation. Your static callback receives an instance object by value. You will find out that this doesn't work as soon as you try to use it. Your current code doesn't use the instance at all so it appears to work for now.

A correct implementation would look like this static void staticCallback(void* instance) { static_cast<Test*>(instance)->actualMemberCallback(); }

The function pointer cast here (and later calling it) is technically UB. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/559581/3966456 (This is a question for C, but the same applies to C++. I tried to find a C++ question to no avail).

There is always a potential danger when using an explicit type conversion (aka typecast) on a void * pointer to another pointer type.   If you convert to the wrong thing in any situation, you have both explicitly told the compiler not to diagnose an invalid conversion AND introduced undefined behaviour when the pointer is dereferenced.    You may wish to consider making your CallbackCaller a templated class.   Although you're not using the standard C++ library (no longer called the STL since early 2000s, BTW), documentation for std::mem_fn may offer a starting point.

You've almost got an idiomatic C-style callback implementation, however staticCallback is incorrect, and trying to force it with casts has lead you into undefined behaviour. Because your example actualMemberCallback doesn't use this, you have unfortunately had the worst symptom of UB, appearing to work.
static void staticCallback(void *instance)
{
    static_cast<Test *>(instance)->actualMemberCallback();
}

Having fixed that, you no longer need to reinterpret_cast when calling attach.
A more C++ way would be to accept function pointers and function objects, and have Test::begin attach a lambda. CallbackCaller is approximately std::function<void()>.
class CallbackCaller
{
    struct BaseCallback
    {
        virtual ~BaseCallback() {}
        virtual void invoke() = 0;
    };
    template <typename F>
    struct Callback : BaseCallback
    {
        Callback(F f) : f(f) {}
        F f;
        void invoke() override { f(); }
    };
    BaseCallback * callback = nullptr; // Should be std::unique_ptr, at which point you can remove the constructors and destructors
    public:
    CallbackCaller() {}
    CallbackCaller(const CallbackCaller&) = delete;
    CallbackCaller& operator=(const CallbackCaller&) = delete;
    ~CallbackCaller() { delete callback; }
    template <typename F>
    void attach(F f) { callback = new Callback<F>{ f }; }
    void call() { if (callback) callback->invoke(); }
};

void Test::begin()
{
    this->callbackCaller.attach([this]{ actualMemberCallback(); });    
}


Thanks, that's a very informative answer. If you don't mind, can you clarify your last example? What is the function of the virtual BaseCallback destructor? Why are Callback and BaseCallback separated in a base struct and an inherited struct?
Why the default CalbackCalller() constructor? Wouldn't that be generated implicitly? I'm assuming you're deleting the copy constructor to prevent an implicit copy constructor being generated leading to UB? Does the same apply for operator=?

@Bas you need a virtual destructor for delete callback to have defined behaviour. Callback is a template, but you need to have one type for the member callback. The empty default constructor is because there are other explicit constructors (the deleted copy). Copying is deleted because the implicit ones would be incorrect, yes
