# Don't understand a piece of code like "....*(BYTE *)p=0xff;...."

Tags: c

The C code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char BYTE; 
int main(void) {
    unsigned int num, *p;
    p=&num;
    num=0;
    *(BYTE *)p=0xff;
}
```

But I do not understand the meaning inside the main function. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `num` is an `unsigned int`
2. `p` is a pointer to that same int.
3. `(BYTE*)p` means *"pretend its really a pointer to a byte instead"*.
4. `*(BYTE*)p =` means *"Go set that byte to be the value on the RHS."*
5. the value on the RHS is `0xFF`.

***Result***: num is a 4-byte integer.
One byte of that int will be set to `0xFF`
(it could be the high-byte or the low-byte depending on your platform)

So `num` will either end up being `0xFF 00 00 00`, or possibly `0x00 00 00 FF`

Comment: There is actually a `num = 0;` in there. (lots of *deja vu* with this question - I bet it's from some course)

Comment: lol,actually it comes from a book. Now i almost understand. Thank you guys .

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the program is undefined.

`(BYTE *)p` is an invalid cast since the types are unrelated.

You cannot cast an `unsigned int*` to an `unsigned char*`. (For example, it's possible that these pointers occupy entirely different memory locations, and the C standard allows for that).

For more details, see [C: When is casting between pointer types not undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810417/c-when-is-casting-between-pointer-types-not-undefined-behavior)

Comment: I tried it and seems ok. But you contribute a good idea. Thank you

Comment: That's the nature of undefined behaviour. One day though the compiler might leap up and eat your cat!