# Is it possible to initialize a C pointer to NULL?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

I had been writing things like

```
char *x=NULL;
```

on the assumption that

```
 char *x=2;
```

would create a `char` pointer to address 2.

But, in [The GNU C Programming Tutorial](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Pointers-and-initialization.html#Pointers%20and%20initialization) it says that `int *my_int_ptr = 2;` stores the integer value `2` to whatever random address is in `my_int_ptr` when it is allocated.

This would seem to imply that my own `char *x=NULL` is assigning whatever the value of `NULL` cast to a `char` is to some random address in memory.

While

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *x=NULL;

    if (x==NULL)
        printf("is NULL\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

does, in fact, print

> is NULL

when I compile and run it, I am concerned that I am relying on undefined behavior, or at least under-specified behavior, and that I should write

```
char *x;
x=NULL;
```

instead.

Comment: There's a very confusing difference between what `int *x = whatever;` does and what `int *x; *x = whatever;` does. `int *x = whatever;` actually behaves like `int *x; x = whatever;`, not `*x = whatever;`.

Comment: This tutorial appears to have gotten that confusing distinction wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I drew conclusion too early. You are right, well spotted. +1, this is a useful question, thanks for asking.

Comment: Ah nvm, indeed thsis tutorial has got it completely backwards :D

Comment: So many shitty tutorials on the web! Stop reading immediately. We really need a SO blacklist where we can publicly shame crappy books...

Comment: @Lundin Most publications have a few errors (in fact it would be unusual for one to be completely error free)  , so I wouldn't judge based on one case; in fact this case is a good candidate for being some kind of typographical error , as the way the text is written suggests that the author intended to draw distinction between initialization and assignment

Comment: @M.M The whole linked page is complete crap, not only is the author missing the blatant constraint violation issue, but they also don't mention that the "garbage values" could as well be trap representations. And they don't mention that a pointer and `int` may have different sizes and representations.

Comment: @Lundin yeah well, it's pretty clear that it's only meant to apply to using gcc on 1980s GNU/Linux systems

Comment: @M.M Which doesn't make it less crappy in the year 2017. Given the evolution of compilers and computers since the 80s, it's basically the same thing as if I were a doctor and reading medicine books written during the 18th century.

Comment: @Lundin: Do a whitelist, its actually orders of magnitude smaller, and oh, we have it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/) which also contains some top blacklist contenders...

Comment: @PlasmaHH I regret contributing to that book list, it should be nuked from the site. Lots of crap there, starting with K&R. It's a bad list and nothing SO should be proud of.

Comment: I don't think this tutorial qualifies as "_The_ GNU C Programming Tutorial"...

Comment: This is a disaster, what kind of information people are putting online for new programmers? hmmm.

Comment: @Lundin: I don’t see K&R as ‘crap’, even if it is not a good way to learn contemporary C.

Comment: @PJTraill If you read it and focus on their coding style and (lack of) program design, you'll realize it was never a good book. It has an undeserved good reputation because 1) for a long while it was the only book and also C canon until C90, and 2) because of nostalgia, Dennis Ritchie worship and other religious reasons.

Comment: @marcelm I agree with the point you're making, but if you follow the "up" links in that page, you get to something clearly *titled* as ["The GNU C Programming Tutorial"](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/index.html#Top). The same content can be found in http://markburgess.org/CTutorial/GNU-ctut.pdf, by Burgess and Hale-Evans, which says Copyright 2002 Free Software Foundation.

Comment: Stop using random tutorials on the internet to learn C, and get yourself a proper, peer-reviewed book. Egads.

Comment: "crasseux.com" ("crasseux" ~ "filthy" In English) seems to be a junk website. It says "This is an archive of abandonware, mp3s, appz and other junk, enjoy." Best avoid it.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

> *Is it possible to initialize a C pointer to NULL?*

**TL;DR** Yes, very much.

---

[The **actual claim made on the guide** reads like](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Pointers-and-initialization.html#Pointers%20and%20initialization)

> *On the other hand, if you use just the single initial assignment, `int *my_int_ptr = 2;`, the program will try to fill the contents of the memory location pointed to by `my_int_ptr` with the value 2. Since `my_int_ptr` is filled with garbage, it can be any address. [...]*

Well, they ***are*** wrong, you are right.

For the statement, (*ignoring, for now, the fact that pointer to integer conversion is an implementation-defined behaviour*)

```
int * my_int_ptr = 2;
```

`my_int_ptr` is a variable (of type pointer to `int`), it has an address of its own (type: address of pointer to integer), you are storing a value of `2` into *that* address.

Now, `my_int_ptr`, being a pointer type, we can say, it *points to* the value of "type" at the memory location *pointed by* the value held in `my_int_ptr`. So, you are essentially assigning the value *of* the pointer variable, not the value of the memory location pointed to by the pointer.

So, for conclusion

```
 char *x=NULL;
```

initializes the pointer variable `x` to `NULL`, not the *value at the memory address pointed to by the pointer*.

This is the **same** as

```
 char *x;
 x = NULL;
```

---

## Expansion:

Now, being strictly conforming, a statement  like

```
 int * my_int_ptr = 2;
```

is illegal, as it involves constraint violation. To be clear,

- `my_int_ptr` is a pointer variable, type `int *`
- an integer constant, `2` has type `int`, by definition.

and they are not "compatible" types, so this initialization is invalid because it's violating the rules of simple assignment, mentioned in chapter §6.5.16.1/P1, described in [Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43339110/2173917).

In case anyone's interested how initialization is linked to simple assignment constraints, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, P11

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. The
> initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); **the same type
> constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the scalar
> to be the unqualified version of its declared type.**

Comment: @Random832n They ___are___ wrong. I've quoted the related part in my answer, please correct me if otherwise. Oh, and the emphasis in intentional.

Comment: "... is illegal, as it involves constraint violation. ... an integer literal, 2 has type int, by definition." is problematic. It sounds like because `2` is an `int`,  the assignment is a problem.  But it is more than that.  `NULL` may also be an `int`, an `int 0`.  It is just that `char *x = 0;` is well defined  and `char *x = 2;` is not.  6.3.2.3 Pointers 3  (BTW: C does not define a _integer literal_, only _string literal_ and _compound literal_.  `0` is an _integer constant_)

Comment: @chux You're very correct, but isn't it `char *x = (void *)0;`, to be conforming? or is it only with other expressions which yields the value `0`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: integer constants with value `0` are special: they implicitly convert to null pointers separately from the usual rules for explicitly casting general integer expressions to pointer types.

Comment: The language described by the *1974 C Reference Manual* did not allow declarations to specify initialization expressions, and the lack of such expressions makes "declaration mirrors use" much more practical.  The syntax `int *p = somePtrExpression` is IMHO rather horrid since it looks like it's setting the value of `*p` but it's actually setting the value of `p`.

Comment: I guess the confusion might arise from char *hello= "hello"; as this does initialize the char * to a block of memory with "hello" in it

Answer (score 54):

The tutorial is wrong.  In ISO C, `int *my_int_ptr = 2;` is an error. In GNU C, it means the same as `int *my_int_ptr = (int *)2;` . This converts the integer `2` to a memory address, in some fashion as determined by the compiler.

It does not attempt to store anything in the location addressed by that address (if any).  If you went on to write `*my_int_ptr = 5;`, then it would try to store the number `5` in the location addressed by that address.

Comment: I didn't know that integer to pointer conversion is implementation defined. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @taskinoor Please note that there's a conversion only in the case you force it by a cast, as in this answer. If not for the cast, the code should not compile.

Comment: @taskinoor: Yes, the various conversions in C are quite confusing. This Q has interesting information on conversions: [C: When is casting between pointer types not undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810417/c-when-is-casting-between-pointer-types-not-undefined-behavior).

Answer (score 18):

To clarify why the tutorial is wrong, `int *my_int_ptr = 2;` is a "constraint violation", it is code which is not allowed to compile and the compiler must give you a diagnostic upon encountering it.

As per 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment:

> Constraints
>
> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has arithmetic type;
> - the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type compatible with the type of the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue
>     conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified
>     versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has
>     all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue
>     conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other
>     is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the
>     type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed
>     to by the right;
> - the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right is a null pointer constant; or
> - the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified _Bool, and the right is a pointer.

In this case the left operand is an unqualified pointer. Nowhere does it mention that the right operand is allowed to be an integer (arithmetic type). So the code violates the C standard.

GCC is known to behave poorly unless you explicitly tell it to be a standard C compiler. If you compile the code as `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`, it will correctly give a diagnostic as it must do.

Comment: upvoted for suggesting -pedantic-errors.  Though I'll likely use the related -Wpedantic .

Comment: One exception to your statement that the right operand is not allowed to be an integer: Section 6.3.2.3 says, “An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant.” Notice the second-to-last bullet point in your quote. Therefore, `int* p = 0;` is a legal way to write `int* p = NULL;`. Although the latter is clearer and more conventional.

Comment: Which makes the pathological obfuscation `int m = 1, n = 2 * 2, * p = 1 - 1, q = 2 - 1;` legal too.

Comment: @Davislor that's covered by bullet point 5 in the standard quote in this answer (agree that the summary afterwards probably should mention it though)

Comment: @chux I believe a well-formed program would need to convert an `intptr_t` explicitly to one of the allowed types on the right-hand side.  That is, `void* a = (void*)(intptr_t)b;` is legal by point 4, but `(intptr_t)b` is neither a compatible pointer type, nor a `void*`, nor a null pointer constant, and `void* a` is neither an arithmetic type nor `_Bool`. The standard says the conversion is legal, but not that it is implicit.

Comment: @chux `void *a = (intptr_t) b;` is not valid C, try it in a standard-conforming C compiler. 7.20.1.4/1 only says that these types may be used to convert to/from a pointer type and back. But the code  `void *a = (intptr_t) b;` does not cause a conversion from `intptr_t` to `void*`, because the right operand of `=` is only converted to the type of the assignment expression (6.1.16.1/2) if the above cited constraints (6.1.16.1/1) are fulfilled. You would have to type `void *a = (void*)(intptr_t)b;` to trigger an explicit conversion.

Comment: @chux The standard says that `0` is a null pointer constant (bullet point 5).  This doesn’t extend to integers in general.

Answer (score 15):

`int *my_int_ptr = 2`

> stores the integer value 2 to whatever random address is in my_int_ptr when it is allocated.

This is completely wrong. If this is actually written then please get a better book or tutorial.

`int *my_int_ptr = 2` defines an integer pointer which points to address 2. You will most likely get a crash if you try to access address `2`.

`*my_int_ptr = 2`, i.e. without the `int` in the line, stores the value two to whatever random address `my_int_ptr` is pointing to. Having saying this, you can assign `NULL` to a pointer when it is defined. `char *x=NULL;` is perfectly valid C.

Edit: While writing this I didn't know that integer to pointer conversion is implementation defined behavior. Please see the good answers by @M.M and @SouravGhosh for details.

Comment: It is completely wrong because it is a constraint violation, not for any other reason. In particular, this is incorrect: "int *my_int_ptr = 2 defines an integer pointer which points to address 2".

Comment: @Lundin: Your phrase _"not for any other reason"_ is itself wrong and misleading. If you fix the type compatibility problem, you are still left with the fact that the tutorial's author is grossly misrepresenting how pointer initialisations and assignments work.

Answer (score 15):

A lot of confusion about C pointers comes from a very bad choice that was originally made regarding coding style, corroborated by a very bad little choice in the syntax of the language.

`int *x = NULL;` is correct C, but it is very misleading, I would even say nonsensical, and it has hindered the understanding of the language for many a novice.  It makes one think that later on we could do `*x = NULL;` which is of course impossible. You see, the type of the variable is not `int`, and the name of the variable is not `*x`, nor does the `*` in the declaration play any functional role in collaboration with the `=`.  It is purely declarative. So, what makes a lot more sense is this:

`int* x = NULL;` which is also correct C, albeit it does not adhere to the original K&R coding style.  It makes it perfectly clear that the type is `int*`, and the pointer variable is `x`, so it becomes plainly evident even to the uninitiated that the value `NULL` is being stored into `x`, which is a pointer to `int`.

Furthermore, it makes it easier to derive a rule: when the star is away from the variable name then it is a declaration, while the star being attached to the name is pointer dereferencing.

So, now it becomes a lot more understandable that further down we can either do `x = NULL;` or `*x = 2;` in other words it makes it easier for a novice to see how `variable = expression` leads to `pointer-type variable = pointer-expression` and `dereferenced-pointer-variable = expression`.  (For the initiated, by 'expression' I mean 'rvalue'.)

The unfortunate choice in the syntax of the language is that when declaring local variables you can say `int i, *p;` which declares an integer and a pointer to an integer, so it leads one to believe that the `*` is a useful part of the name. But it is not, and this syntax is just a quirky special case, added for convenience, and in my opinion it should have never existed, because it invalidates the rule that I proposed above. As far as I know, nowhere else in the language is this syntax meaningful, but even if it is, it points to a discrepancy in the way pointer types are defined in C.  Everywhere else, in single-variable declarations, in parameter lists, in struct members, etc. you can declare your pointers as `type* pointer-variable` instead of `type *pointer-variable`; it is perfectly legal and makes more sense.

Comment: `int *x = NULL; is correct C, but it is very misleading, I would even say nonsensical,`... I have to agree to disagree. `It makes one think`....stop thinking, read a C book first, no offense.

Comment: @SouravGhosh As a matter of opinion I think that C **should** have been designed so that `int* somePtr, someotherPtr` declares two pointers, in fact, I used to write `int* somePtr` but that leads to the bug you describe.

Comment: @fagricipni I stopped using the multiple variable declaration syntax because of this.  I declare my variables one by one.  If I really want them on the same line, I separate them with semi-colons rather than commas.  "If a place is bad, don't go to that place."

Comment: @fagricipni Well, if I could have designed linux from scratch, I would have used `create` instead of `creat`. :) The point is, it is how it is and we need to mould ourselves to adapt to that. It all boils down to personal choice at the end of the day, agree.

Comment: How do you explain `int* y[10];` ?  This declares `y` to have type `int*[10]`.

Comment: @M.M I can't really explain it, I regard it as one more of those weird things about C.  But at the same time, `int *y[10]` does not make things any clearer.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to add something orthogonal to the many excellent answers. Actually, initializing to `NULL` is far from bad practice and may be handy if that pointer may or may not be used to store a dynamically allocated block of memory.

```
int * p = NULL;
...
if (...) {
    p = (int*) malloc(...);
    ...
}
...
free(p);
```

Since according to the [ISO-IEC 9899 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) `free` is a nop when the argument is `NULL`, the code above (or something more meaningful along the same lines) is legit.

Comment: It's redundant to cast the result of malloc in C, unless that C code should also compile as C++.

Comment: You are right, the `void*` is converted as needed. But having code that works  with a C and a C++ compiler could have benefits.

Comment: @LucaCiti C and C++ are different languages.  There are only errors waiting for you if you try to compile a source file written for one using a compiler designed for the other.  It's like trying to write C code that you can compile using Pascal tools.

Comment: @MikeofSST A common use case of code that must compile as either C or C++ is library header files. You can write two versions and use `#ifdef __cplusplus` to select the language, but that adds failure modes and violates DRY. It’s a lot simpler and safer in those cases to write code that works everywhere. Granted, a call to `malloc()` is unlikely to appear in a header file. Besides, the cast is benign and some people think it improves clarity.

Comment: @Davislor I'll take your word for that: it's not a use case that I've seen since about 1990, but that doesn't mean it doesn't still exist.  For new projects, I would strongly recommend that the two are treated as completely incompatible languages, as different as F# and APL.  How do you guarantee that you pick the correct library?  C and C++ have different calling conventions and linking the wrong one would cause all hell to break loose, even if you could get it to build.  Sounds like too much risk for too little reward to me.

Comment: Good advice. I (try to) always initialize my pointer constants to something. In modern C, this can usually be their final value and they can be `const` pointers declared *in medias res*, but even when a pointer needs to be mutable (like one used in a loop or by `realloc()`), setting it to `NULL` catches bugs where it’s used before it’s set with its real value. On most systems, dereferencing `NULL` causes a segfault at the point of failure (although there are exceptions), whereas an uninitialized pointer contains garbage and writing to it corrupts arbitrary memory.

Comment: Also, it’s very easy to see in the debugger that a pointer contains `NULL`, but can be very difficult to tell a garbage pointer from a valid one. So it’s helpful to ensure that all pointers are always either valid or `NULL`, from the moment of declaration.

Comment: @MikeofSST Looking up the first example that comes to mind, the glibc version of `<stdio.h>`, line 27 is `#ifdef __cplusplus`. By the C++ standard, all C++ compilers must support `#include <stdio.h>`, for example. I rarely if ever see C libraries that *prohibit* calling them from C++ programs. I agree that it is very rare to see anything but the kind of function prototypes, `extern` variable definitions and macros that typically appear in C header files written for both languages, though. More likely, people who learned C++ first just got in the habit.

Comment: @MikeofSST So, kind of like why I write `++i;` instead of `i++;` in both languages unless I actually care about the return value. In C++, with arbitrary classes, that saves the compiler from creating an unnecessary temporary object. I just didn’t spare the neurons to do it differently in C.

Comment: @cat Exactly. In C, or in C++ with integral and pointer types, it doesn’t matter. But, in C++ with more complex classes and operator overloading, it can make a big difference! So I got in the habit of doing it the way that always works. I suspect that’s why many people cast `void*` return values explicitly.

Comment: Can I be pedantic? (Ehm, as if...) The code in this answer has a potential memory leak, because it says `p = malloc(...` without checking if `p` is still `NULL`. Also, the question was about C, so why is this comment thread about C++?

Comment: You can be pedantic, of course :-)     But I think you seem to miss the point. I have written a stub just to show that by setting `p` to `NULL` you can free it even if you take a branch that ends up not touching `p`. If it was not initialized you would get a segfault. Davislor added a couple of points more, e.g. that a NULL is easier to spot during debug. This all applies to c as well. The only c++ specific point is a detail (not the main point) i.e. the cast.

Comment: The code as it is has no leak simply because it doesn't specify what is in the ellipses :-D      But you are right, depending on what you put in the ellipses you need to check `p` before assigning it to the result of the `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct.

```
int main()
{
    char * x = NULL;

    if (x==NULL)
        printf("is NULL\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This function is correct for what it does. It assigns the address of 0 to the char pointer x. That is, it points the pointer x to the memory address 0.

Alternative:

```
int main()
{
    char* x = 0;

    if ( !x )
        printf(" x points to NULL\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My guess as to what you wanted is:

```
int main()
{
    char* x = NULL;
    x = alloc( sizeof( char ));
    *x = '2';

    if ( *x == '2' )
        printf(" x points to an address/location that contains a '2' \n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

x is the street address of a house. *x examines the contents of that house.
```

Comment: "It assigns the address of 0 to the char pointer x." --> Maybe.  C does not specify the _value_ of the pointer, only that `char* x = 0; if (x == 0)` will be true.  Pointers are not necessarily integers.

Comment: It doesn't 'point the pointer x to the memory address 0'. It sets the pointer value to an *unspecified* invalid value that can be *tested* by comparing it to 0, or NULL. The actual operation is implementation-defined. There is nothing here that answers the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

this is a null pointer

```
int * nullPtr = (void*) 0;
```

Comment: This answers the title, but not the body of the question.