# Why can't I directly assign an int to an int pointer like this: int *p = 6;?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, initialization, variable-assignment

error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
`int *q = 8;`

Works fine.
`*q = 6;`

Why can't I directly assign an int to an int pointer like this: `int *q = 6`; and I can assign it safely in the next line?

Comment: Initialization vs assignment

Comment: Try not to write multi-language source files. It's very difficult to do it, and the result isn't exactly any of the selected languages.

Comment: *and I can assign it safely in the next line* - No! The pointer is not initialized. You can't dereference it.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya that's why I wrote an answer, it's really important and was missing on the other answers so far (now it's in some other answers as well).

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes, it should also be a part of the accepted answer.

Comment: I prefer to write always **int* q** and not **int *q** during declaration. Semantically they are same, but first one clearly indicates the type of the variable more clearly.

Comment: Given that this has more answers and higher scores all around than the duplicate, it would be better to close the other post as a duplicate of this instead of closing this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because they're different things at all. The 1st one is definition of variable with initializer expression, i.e an [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (of the pointer itself):

```
int *         q                      = 8;
~~~~~         ~                      ~~~
type is int*; name of variable is q; initialized with 8
```

The 2nd one is assignment (of the object pointed by the pointer):

```
*q                              = 6;
~~                              ~~~
dereference on q via operator*; assign the resulting lvalue pointed by q to 6
```

And, `int *p = 6;` means define a variable named `p` with type `int*` and initialize it with `6`, which fails because `6` can't be used for initializing a pointer directly (i.e. the error "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'").

Answer (score 14):

`*` symbol is reused for two different purpuses in your snippet. First time it is used as a part of type declaration `int *`, declaring a pointer to int. Second time it is used to dereference a pointer `*q`, invoking indirection operator.

`*` can also be used to invoke multiplication operator `*q = *q * *q;`;

To assign a value to an integer pointed by pointer you need to dereference it. And to assigning integral value other than 0 to a pointer itself (that is what `int *q = 8;` is doing) requires `reinterpret_cast`, hence you get this error.

Comment: "Two different purposes" is in fact untrue. Let's look at the definition of _two_ pointers: `int *p, *q;`. If the `*` belonged to `int`, you would define two pointers as `int* p, q /*wrong*/;` This is an unfortunate remnant of C compatibility, because in other contexts such as `std::vector<int*>` it *is* part of the type..

Answer (score 6):

Statement `int *q` defines a variable of type "pointer to integer", and an initialisation therefore needs to be a pointer value, not an integral value.
So `int *q = 8` is not the same as `int *q; *q = 8` (which would be undefined behaviour because it dereferences an uninitialized pointer), but more like `int *q; q = 8`, which makes the misunderstanding more transparent.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
int *q = 8;
```

is an initialization. It initializes `q` (the pointer), not `*q` (what it points to). Writing this equivalently with an assignment instead of initialization would look like:

```
int *q;
q = 8;
```

So you see it doesn't make sense. (and, isn't allowed of course -- an `int` is not a pointer)

Just to be sure, if you write:

```
int *q;
*q = 8;
```

this is *syntactically* correct, but *undefined behavior*. Your pointer doesn't point to an object of type `int`, it is uninitialized and probably pointing to some invalid location. Writing there, anything could happen.

Comment: No it is not syntactically correct. You cannot assign an integer to a pointer, it is a constraint violation of simple assignment. (Initialization follows the same rule)

Comment: I was referring to the first line, which will not compile since it is a constraint violation.

Comment: @Lundin and I think my text is clear enough to understand "*syntactically correct*" refers to the last snippet, if you read it carefully.

Comment: Still the first line will not compile. It will not initialize the pointer as you claim, because it will not compile.

Comment: @Lundin I don't claim such a thing.

Comment: @Lundin talking about the *syntax* and it's elaborated later. I don't claim this to be valid code.

Answer (score 3):

Because the types don't match.

The `6` itself is not a value of pointer type, it's an integer so it cannot be directly stored in a pointer.

When you do `*q = 6` the `*` *dereferences* the pointer, so the type becomes `int` (or rather an lvalue `int`, i.e. something that can be assigned to).

Answer (score 3):

Here, assign the value `8` to an object of type `int*`. It means `q` points on address `8` on memory.

```
 int *q = 8;
```

Is **equivalent** to:

```
int *q;
q = 8;
```

Is **Not equivalent** to:

```
int *q;
*q = 8;
```

is **illegal**, as it involves **constraint violation**.

Related stack overflow question: [Is it possible to initialize a C pointer to NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338084/is-it-possible-to-initialize-a-c-pointer-to-null)

Comment: your "is illegal as it involves constraint violation" refers to the OP's code - they way you format your post it looks like you might be talking about your last code snippet (which is not a constraint violation)

Answer (score 3):

A pointer variable holds an address, or 'location' of something.  Thus, the pointer holds a value that is a memory address.  When you say:

```
int *q = 6;
```

you are creating a pointer variable that intends to point to an int, and telling it to point to the int value stored in the address 6, which is (probably) not what you really intended.

A pointer variable should point to some memory address that contains some actual data you want to access.  For example:

```
int x = 5;
int *q = &x;
```

This creates a variable (x) that contains the value 5.
the next line creates a pointer variable that contains the address of x.  You have set the pointer variable 'q' to the address of the int variable 'x'.

Now you can see what is at 'x' by doing this:

```
int y;
y = *q;
```

This says "take what is pointed to by q, and store it in y".  The end effect is that y will be set to 5.

```
int x = 5;     // create variable x and set it to 5
int *q = &x;   // create int pointer variable, set it to the address of x
int y;         // create variable y
y = *q;        // take the value pointed to by q, and store it in y
```

If, for example the variable x is at memory location 1234, and you looked at the value stored in 'q', it would be 1234, which is the address of x.
When you say "y = *q", you are saying "take the value stored in the address 1234, and puts that value in y".  Since the memory location 1234 is 'x', and 'x' was assigned the value 5, the value 5 will be what is stored at the address 1234.

```
y = *q;
```

will take the value stored in the address 1234 and assign y to that value, thus making y 5, which was the value stored in x, which is what q 'points' to.

This could be shortened to:

```
int x = 5;
int *q = &x;
int y = *q;
```

Comment: That answers only first half of the question, but not the second one: " and I can assign it safely in the next line?"

Answer (score 2):

When you write
`int *q = 8;` it means you declared a pointer `q` and initialized a pointer with the integer 8. but q being a pointer expects a `address value` therefore you get error stating incompatibility.
Whereas when you write
`*q=8` after declaring, it means you are dereferencing the addresses pointed by `q` and writing a value to that location. here `q` points to a `int` so you are writing `8` a integer value to the location pointed by `q`. that is right. This can also lead to error at runtime if `q` is not initialized to point to right location.

Comment: You can't initialize a pointer with an integer, because initialization follows the rules of "simple assignment". You would have to convert the integer to a pointer first.

Comment: Thanks. i dint explicitly tell that the problem is that integer is assigned to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In your first statement you are declaring and initializing the pointer to some value of type `int` (on the same line). In your second statement you are changing the value pointed to by a pointer. Two different things. What you have there is initialization followed by an assignment. Don't let the `*` confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not valid C, simple as that. Specifically, it is a constraint violation of the assignment operator, since integer to pointer or pointer to integer is not valid forms of "simple assignment" (C11 6.5.16.1).

You can convert between integers and pointers by adding an explicit cast. The result is however not guaranteed to work: pointers and integers may have different representations and there might be alignment issues.

In case of `*q = 6;` you assign an int to an int, which is of course perfectly fine (given that the pointer points at allocated memory somewhere).

Answer (score -1):

If you re-write it like this:

```
int* q = 8; 
    *q = 6;
```

Then you can see the `*` has two different purposes.

Comment: How? This code will not compile on a conforming C compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
int *q = new int(8);
```

But working with pointers here is not normally required. If you have to use pointer, use smart pointer `shared_ptr<int>` or `uniqe_ptr<int>`.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you are assigning value 8 to pointer *q and it wont work during initialization, Memory address is unique at that time not available to assign but you can set once memory block created after initialization for *q.