# Is there a failsafe way to determine the alignment/trailing bits of a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion, cross-platform, undefined-behavior

In C, a pointer is aligned to a certain if a certain number of trailing bits are zeros. This requires extracting the bits of a pointer, albeit only bounded number of trailing bits. The obvious way is to cast a pointer to `uintptr_t` and use a bitmask:

```
void *my_ptr;
bool aligned_to_16 = (uintptr_t)my_ptr & 15;
```

However, the C standard does not require `uintptr_t` as that is an optional type. This might be if a pointer is too big to fit in an integer. However that **should** not matter, since we only care about the trailing bits anyway. So what if I just cast to `unsigned char` or `int`?

Well, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818640/16217248) answer, that is still undefined behavior, even if we do not care about the leading bits that would cause the value to not fit:

> As far as I can tell, all other casts of a pointer to a pointer of a different type are undefined behavior. In particular, if you are not casting to char or a sufficiently large integer type, it may always be UB to cast a pointer to a different pointer type - even without dereferencing it.

I cannot find any failsafe Standards-compliant way to extract the actual trailing bits of a pointer, for example to test the pointer alignment, that does not invoke any optional features, or implementation-defined/unspecified/undefined behavior. But is there in fact a way, besides executing `snprintf()` with a `%p` format specifier and parsing the results?

Comment: Just because it's not required doesn't mean it's not widely supported. What platforms are you trying to port to that omit it?

Comment: @tadman Currently, none. However, I was wondering if there is a strictly conforming way in theory.

Comment: I don't think so. Portable code shouldn't care about such details.

Comment: @Barmar The C standard mentions alignment though. So there ought to be a way to check if a pointer is aligned.

Comment: Note that even when `uintptr_t` is provided, it theoretically might not do what you want. There's no requirement that the integer value be the same as the pointer address, just that you can convert back and forth between the types. It would be valid for `ptr->uintptr_t` to add 1, and subtract 1 when going the other way.

Comment: @Barmar What happens if I type-pun them, say, using a union? I take it there is no guarantee casting a pointer to a `uintptr_t` then using a union to bitcast between them?

Comment: But in practice, your code should work practically everywhere.

Comment: There's practical portability, in which case this is likely to exist, and theoretical portability, which means there might be some system where, for *reasons*, the alignment is really, really weird, and `0x....73` might actually be 16-byte aligned *somehow*, like if that's actually mapped to some 20-bit words in memory or who knows what. I'm sure with FPGAs you can cook up some really insanely strange CPUs that still, somehow, run compiled C code.

Comment: @tadman So there is no 'failsafe' way strictly speaking, but in practice, what I have will work on any system worth porting to.

Comment: If you find a system where this *doesn't* work, please get back to us as we can all have a chuckle at how utterly batty that is, and we'll want to know more.

Comment: In 2022/2023, the STDC committee thought it was worth ditching support for non-2's Complement representations, but for some reason, they did not think it was worth ditching support for theoretical machines where the alignment of a pointer is in fact not reflected by the divisibility of the trailing bits.

Comment: What good would this do you? Even if you had a way to test alignment that was fully specified by the C standard, what does that enable you to do that is also specified by the C standard and not implementation-dependent? You cannot convert it to another type based in the alignment test and then use that type to access an object, because that does not conform to the aliasing rules, except for contrived circumstances. So anything you are going to use this for will be implementation-dependent, so you might as well use an implementation-dependent way of testing alignment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I could use a union to bitcast the data.

Comment: You're making assumptions about the format of pointers; the presence or absence of `uintptr_t` is the last thing you should be worrying about! This falls into the category of "worry about it when it fails". Keep in mind it will fail at compile-time if the env doesn't have `uintptr_t`, so the problem is immediately obvious when the code is ported to this other highly unusual platform.

Comment: @ikegami True. Typically I use `static_assert` for environmental constrains, but in this case, I won't even need one because it will fail at compile-time regardless.

Comment: Even if `uintptr_t` exists, this is not a portable way to check if a pointer is aligned (btw, you seem to be missing a "not"). From a standard perspective, pointers should meet alignment requirements "by construction", it is not something the application code should worry about (unless trying to do non-standard things).

Comment: @nielsen The reason is I want a function that can handle aligned OR non-aligned pointers, but I need to make the non-aligned pointers aligned first IF they are not aligned. Even if I can know at the call site if the pointer is aligned or not, I want the function body to be able to know so I won't have to create multiple functions. (This is just one example of why I might want to know if a pointer is aligned or not without necessarily having to do non-standard things)

Comment: @user16217248 If the goal is [handle aligned OR non-aligned pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491722/is-there-a-failsafe-way-to-determine-the-alignment-trailing-bits-of-a-pointer-in#comment136616179_77491722),  post a question of how to do that.  Here it sounds like "I have problem X and made solution Y.  Is Y good enough?".

Comment: @user16217248 "besides executing snprintf() with a %p format specifier and parsing the results?" --> Parsing that has many pitfalls with its implementation defined output.  IMO, focus on the higher level issue and not this question's candidate solution.

Comment: `void *my_ptr; int aligned_to_32 = !((uintptr_t)my_ptr & 31);` can fail for the venerable DOS [segment:/offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) pointer, depending on how such a pointer is converted to an integer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't think there is an XY problem. I was simply providing an example of a use-case for knowing the alignment of a pointer, that does not or might not rely on other implementation defined behavior.

Comment: Why need to know the alignment of a pointer?  (And I think it is not the _alignment of a pointer_ you want, but the _alignment of a pointed to object_)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Curiosity. I was wondering if it can be done in as portable a way as possible. The alignment of the pointed to object, yes.

Comment: @user16217248 Merely constructing a pointer to a type that doesn't meet the alignment requirements for that type [invokes undefined behaivor](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7): "If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that pointers identify hardware addresses.  An implementation could represent each pointer value as a combination of an index in a table of allocations and an offset within that allocation.  Some C compilers for the 80286, for example, work in such a fashion.  While the implementations I know of that do such things would generally perform pointer-to-integer conversions in a manner that would put the bottom bits of the offset into the bottom bits of the integer, there's no requirement that they do so.

On the other hand, the Standard's failure to mandate that all implementations behave in a manner common to 99% of them doesn't imply that compiler writers shouldn't generally do so anyway, limiting deviations to those which have an *obvious or documented and compelling justification*.  It also doesn't imply that programmers should jump through hoops to accommodate contrary behavior unless they need to target implementations where such behavior would be justifiable, or whose authors would view the Standard's allowance for such deviation as justification in and of itself.

Comment: Re “… failure to … doesn't imply that … shouldn't … refrain … deviate … in the absence … for doing otherwise…”: Double negatives are a misdemeanor, quadruple negatives are a felony, and septuple negatives are a capital crime. Do not expect anybody to understand this writing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Better?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way indeed is to cast the pointer as `(uintptr_t)` and mask the resulting value with a bitmask.  Yet in your example `my_ptr` is uninitialized so you do have an undefined behavior there which the compiler might exploit for some uncanny optimisation :) Furthermore the boolean `aligned_to_16` thus computed would be true if the pointer is **not** aligned on 16 bytes.

Assuming the type `uintptr_t` is present on your target, and the pointer is valid, the behavior is *implementation defined*, which is as good as you will get trying to achieve non portable implementation dependent tricks.

So the answer is: No, there is no failsafe Standards-compliant way to extract the actual trailing bits of a pointer, even using `snprintf` with a `%p` conversion, but implementation-defined is not a problem if you really need this info.

It would take a perverse system (think [DS9K](http://wikibin.org/articles/deathstation-9000.html)) to prevent you from getting meaningful results from this approach.

Fiddling with the low bits of a pointer is commonly used in hand-optimized implementations of:

- `memcpy`, `memmove`, `memset`, and other string functions
- interpreters using tagged pointers for dynamically typed objects
- memory allocators (using the low bits of chaining pointers for flags)

None of the above is fully portable, but works on most current architectures.  You should not worry about exotic hardware until you actually need to port your software.

Finally, you should ask yourself: *Do I really need to resort to low-level non-portable hacks, or am I just indulging in premature optimisation?*

Comment: *Fiddling with the low bits of a pointer...*  That can be extremely non-portable. My earlier comment is buried in the 20 or so comments on the question itself, but [merely creating a pointer to a type that doesn't meet alignment requirements for that type invokes undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7): "If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."  There's no dereference necessary to invoke UB.  Any alignment-related code is going to be very implementation dependent.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: true but so unlikely. Do you have examples in mind?

Comment: ARM and SPARC CPUs have strict alignment requirements that will cause a `SIGBUS` if violated, but IME those won't barf until the pointer is dereferenced, but I tried to avoid doing that so my experience doesn't exactly preclude merely creating a pointer causing problems. Importantly, per 6.3.2.3p7 an optimizing compiler can assume a misaligned pointer can't happen and that opens the door to all kinds of problems. ISTR a (Raymond Chen?) blog post about the old segmented-memory model on the original x86 CPUs about how playing games with those pointers could cause all kinds of mischief.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: yes, invalid selectors (the high word of segmented pointers) could cause a segmentation fault by just loading the pointer value into a pair of registers (`LES BX,DWORD PTR myptr`).  But here we are only looking at the low bits, and of course changing these bits must be done carefully to avoid creating misaligned pointers for their type.

Comment: @chqrlie: If ARM clang is given something like `union u { unsigned short hh[4]; unsigned ll[2]; }; void test(union u *p)` and that function tries to access `p->hh[0]` and `p->hh[1]`, clang may replace the two 16-bit accesses with a single 32-bit accesses, on the presumption that every pointer to a union will be aligned to satisfy the coarsest union member that exists, rather than the coarsest member that is dereferenced.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: See my above comment.  Even if code as written never performs a 32-bit access, clang may convert a sequence of 16-bit (or 8-bit) accesses to something it "knows" is 32-bit aligned into a single 32-bit access.