# Is it possible to cast printf as a parameter to another function?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, function-pointers

I am working on a linked list library and here is a function I wrote:

```
/**
 * go through a linked list and perform function func for every node of the
 * linked list
 *
 * func is a function pointer to the function you would to apply on the node.
 * it should return 0 if it is successful and non-zero value otherwise.
 */
void traverse_list(linkedlist * ll, int (* func)(void * args)){
    node * temp;

    temp = ll->head;
    while( temp != NULL ){
        if((* func)(temp->val))
            fprintf(stderr,"Error processing value!\n");
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

My question is simple, I tried something like  `travers_list(testlinkedlist,printf)` but it just cannot work(printf not printing anything out), what I am doing wrong? Can I do it at all, if I can, how?

Comment: You can definitely do it. Not sure the syntax off the top of my head.

Comment: You can cast between function pointers, but what is the actual error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: @Falmarri: I think this question is about the syntax for *variadic* function pointers, so not a duplicate.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118889/what-happens-if-i-cast-a-function-pointer-changing-the-number-of-parameters

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, it can compile but printf just does not work.

Comment: What if you change `func` declaration to one that matches `printf` : `int (* func)(const char *format, ...)` ?

Comment: @qrdl yeah that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code snippet to help you out:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*func)(const char* format, ...);

int main()
{
    func a = printf;
    a("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you want to create your own function that takes a variable number of arguments in C, [this page from the GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html#Variadic-Functions) is a good resource to use that explains how variadic functions work.

Comment: what does ... mean in typedef?

Comment: @dorafmon: It means the function takes a variable number of arguments -- as `printf` does.

Comment: It signifies a variadic function ... i.e., there can be an unlimited number of following arguments, although those arguments will need to match the actual format of `printf` in this case since that is what you want to create a pointer to.

Comment: I just realized a problem here, how can you access variable that is represented by ... inside a function?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html#Variadic-Functions

Comment: @Jason Cheers dude. Very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own function type that takes your list element as a parameter.
There is no point in creating traversal procedure taking function as argument if the only function that matches is `printf`. (printf has quite unique signature)

Comment: static int printfAnInt(void * val){
    printf("%d\n",*((int *)val));
    return 0;
}
Thats what i did before.

Comment: @dorafmon Exactly. So you can use more functions than just printf, or predefine parameters. Consider: `printfAnIntToFile(void * val){ sprintf(globalDumplogHandle, "%d\n",*((int *)val)); return 0; }`

Comment: What does globalDumplogHandle mean here?

Comment: @dorafmon globally defined handle to a file, `FILE*`. opened before calling `traverse_list` and closed after.

Comment: Thanks dude! It's something new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast printf to your function's argument type:

```
traverse_list(my_list, (int (*) (void*))&printf);
```

Remember to cast it back before using it, or this is going to end up in undefined behavior.

(I'm assuming you do not want to change the parameters of your function here.)

EDIT:

If what you're really asking is what parameters should your function take, then it should be a pointer to function that corresponds to the synopsis of printf, which you can find in `man 3 printf`:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```