# What are the parameters in this C qsort function call?

Tags: c, pointers

```
qsort(bt->rw[t], bt->num[t], 
      sizeof(TRELLIS_ATOM *), 
      (int (*)(const void *,const void *))compare_wid);
```

`bt->rw[t]` is a pointer to struct pointer, `bt->[num]` is an `int`, I don't understand what that fourth parameter is, except that compare_wid is a function defined somewhere as follows:

```
static int compare_wid( TRELLIS_ATOM* a, TRELLIS_ATOM* b )
{
   ...
   return x;
}
```

Comment: The code as written is wrong.  Please see my answer for details.

Comment: See the accepted answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188839/function-pointer-cast-to-different-signature

Comment: @Alok: the code as written is quite correct.  Without the cast it would be incorrect.  `compare_wid` decays to a pointer to a function returning an integer and taking two pointers.  Any `T*` is equivalent to `void*` as far as the invoking code is concerned and the `const` portion disappears after type checking anyway.

Comment: @D.Shawley: not really.  Any function pointer can be cast to any other function pointer and back to the same type, and the result should be the original function pointer (6.3.2.3p8 n1256), *but* `qsort()` has no way of knowing that `compare_wid()` takes two `TRELLIS_ATOM *` values, so it can't do that conversion.  It therefore calls `compare_wid()` as if it took two `void *` values.  This is undefined behavior.  See http://www.c-faq.com/lib/qsort2.html for details.

Comment: @D.Shawley: if you have to brute force the call to qsort() or bsearch() to get the function pointer acceptable, then the function pointer is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(int (*)(const void *,const void *))` means "treat what follows as a pointer to a function that takes two parameters of type `const void*` and returns an `int`". `compare_wid` is indeed a function that can be treated this way.

`qsort` will call this function to perform comparisons between items when sorting: if the integer it returns is zero, the items are assumed to be equal, otherwise the sign of the integer is used to order them.

Answer (score 22):

I will get to the meaning of the line in a bit, but before I do that, let's get some of the basics of why `qsort()` needs its final parameter of the type it needs.  `qsort()` is a function that can sort any type of data.

You provide it with:

- a base pointer, which points to the start of a contiguous block of data,
- the number of elements in the block,
- the size of one data member, and
- a function that compares two data values.

Since a sorting algorithm in general doesn't depend upon the type of the data being sorted, `qsort()` can be written without the knowledge of what data types it is sorting.  But to be able to do that, `qsort()` takes `void *` parameters, which means "generic pointer" in C.

Let's say you have an array of unsorted `int` values:

```
#define N 1024
int data[N] = { 10, 2, 3, -1, ... } /* 1024 values */
```

Then you can sort them by calling `qsort()`:

```
qsort(data, N, sizeof data[0], compare_int);
```

`data` is of type `int *` when passed to `qsort()`, and the first parameter of `qsort()` is of type `void *`.  Since any object pointer can be converted to `void *` in C, this is OK.  The next two arguments are okay too.  The final argument, `compare_int`, should be a function that takes two `const void *` parameters and returns an `int`.  The function will be called by `qsort()` with pairs of pointers from `&data[0]` to `&data[N-1]` as many times as it needs.

To declare a function `f()` that "takes two `const void *` parameters and returns `int`":

```
int f(const void *, const void *);
```

If one wants to declare a function pointer that we can set to `f`, the pointer is declared as:

```
int (*pf)(const void *, const void *);
pf = f;
```

The parentheses are required, because otherwise `pf` would be a function returning an `int *`.  Now, `pf` is a pointer to a function returning `int`.

Getting back to our `int` sorting algorithm, and from the above, we could define `compare_int()` as:

```
int compare_int(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *the_a = a;
    const int *the_b = b;
    if (*the_a > *the_b) return 1;
    else if (*the_a < *the_b) return -1;
    else return 0;
}
```

While writing `compare_int()`, we know that the pointers passed are `int *` disguised as `void *`, so we convert them back to `int *`, which is OK, and then we compare the numbers.

Now, we turn our attention to the code in question:

```
static int compare_wid( TRELLIS_ATOM* a, TRELLIS_ATOM* b )
```

means that `compare_wid` is a function that takes two `TRELLIS_ATOM *` parameters, and returns an `int`.  As we just saw, the last argument to `qsort()` should be a function that is of type:

```
int (*)(const void *, const void *)
```

I.e., a function taking two `const void *` parameters and returning `int`.  Since the types don't match, the programmer cast `compare_wid()` to the type required by `qsort()`.

However, this has problems.  A function of type:

```
int (*)(TRELLIS_ATOM *, TRELLIS_ATOM *)
```

is not equivalent to a function of type:

```
int (*)(const void *, const void *)
```

so it's not guaranteed if the cast will work.  It is much more easier, correct, and standard to declare `compare_wid()` as:

```
static int compare_wid(const void *a, const void *b);
```

And the definition of `compare_wid()` should look like:

```
static int compare_wid(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const TRELLIS_ATOM *the_a = a;
    const TRELLIS_ATOM *the_b = b;
    ...
    /* Now do what you have to do to compare the_a and the_b */
    return x;
}
```

If you do that, you won't need the cast in the call to `qsort()`, and your program will not only be easier to read, but also correct.

If you can't change `compare_wid()`, then write another function:

```
static int compare_stub(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return compare_wid(a, b);
}
```

and call `qsort()` with `compare_stub()` (without the cast) instead of `compare_wid()`.

*Edit*: Based upon many of the wrong answers, here is a test program:

```
$ cat qs.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct one_int {
    int num;
};

#ifdef WRONG
static int compare(const struct one_int *a, const struct one_int *b)
{
#else
static int compare(const void *a_, const void *b_)
{
    const struct one_int *a = a_;
    const struct one_int *b = b_;
#endif
    if (a->num > b->num) return 1;
    else if (a->num < b->num) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct one_int data[] = {
        { 42 },
        { 1 },
        { 100 }
    };
    size_t n = sizeof data / sizeof data[0];

    qsort(data, n, sizeof data[0], compare);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `compare()` defined as taking two `const struct one_int *` values:

```
$ gcc -DWRONG -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall qs.c
qs.c: In function `main':
qs.c:32: warning: passing argument 4 of `qsort' from incompatible pointer type
```

Compiling with the correct definition:

```
$ gcc -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall qs.c
$
```

*Edit 2*: There seems to be some confusion about the legality of using `compare_wid` as-it-is for the final argument to `qsort()`.  The [comp.lang.c FAQ, question 13.9](http://www.c-faq.com/lib/qsort2.html) has a good explanation (emphasis mine):

> To understand why the curious pointer conversions in a `qsort` comparison function are necessary (*and why a cast of the function pointer when calling `qsort` can't help*), it's useful to think about how `qsort` works. `qsort` doesn't know anything about the type or representation of the data being sorted: it just shuffles around little chunks of memory. (All it knows about the chunks is their size, which you specify in `qsort`'s third argument.) To determine whether two chunks need swapping, `qsort` calls your comparison function. (To swap them, it uses the equivalent of `memcpy`.)
>
> Since `qsort` deals in a generic way with chunks of memory of unknown type, it uses generic pointers `(void *)` to refer to them. When `qsort` calls your comparison function, it passes as arguments two generic pointers to the chunks to be compared. Since it passes generic pointers, your comparison function must accept generic pointers, and convert the pointers back to their appropriate type before manipulating them (i.e. before performing the comparison). A `void` pointer is not the same type as a structure pointer, and on some machines it may have a different size or representation (which is why these casts are required for correctness).

As mentioned in the FAQ, also see [this](http://www.c-faq.com/lib/qsort.msb.html).

Comment: +1 for the time  & effort that you spent to post this answer.

Comment: good answer, but you should use "the_a" and "the_b" in "compare_int()"

Comment: Wow, for decades I've thought a pointer was a pointer was a pointer, and that a `void*` is the wildcard pointer - isomorphic to all. Thank you for the detailed explanation, and in particular the last link. Took some convincing for me to see I'd been wrong all this time!

Comment: @HeathRaftery thank you!  I think function pointers and passing them correctly to other functions is a little tricky.

Answer (score 3):

[qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/)

```
void qsort ( void * base, size_t num, size_t size, 
                    int ( * comparator ) ( const void *, const void * ) );
```

> **comparator**: Function that compares two
>   elements. The function shall follow
>   this prototype:
>
> int comparator ( const void * elem1,
>   const void * elem2 );
>
> The function must accept two
>   parameters that are pointers to
>   elements, type-casted as void*. These
>   parameters should be cast back to some
>   data type and be compared.
>
> The return value of this function
>   should represent whether elem1 is
>   considered less than, equal to, or
>   greater than elem2 by returning,
>   respectively, a negative value, zero
>   or a positive value.

Answer (score 2):

The fourth parameter contains an explicit cast to a function pointer:

```
int (*)(const void *,const void *)
```

- the `int` part correspond to the return type
- the `(*)` part is the notation for a function pointer
- the `(const void *,const void *)` part are the parameter types

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Integer comparison function for use with the stdlib's Qsort. */
inline int int_compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
        return ( *(int*)p1 - *(int*)p2 );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a predicate function that is called by the `qsort` implementation to compare two `TRELLIS_ATOM*`'s.

Answer (score -1):

This is a custom sort function for elements of type `TRELLIS_ATOM` (whatever that might be).

`compare_wid` should return something < 0 if `*a < *b`, > 0 if `*a > *b` and 0 if `*a` and `*b` are logically considered equal.

Answer (score -1):

That is a quicksort function which requires a function pointer to your custom sort handler routine. Hence the typecasting for the parameter for function pointer in the fourth parameter.

When the quick sort function gets called, it executes the function pointer that you supplied to handle the sorting algorithm, i.e `TRELLIS_ATOM *a`, and `TRELLIS_ATOM *b`, and you then do a comparison check between the two, and return a 1, 0, or -1 in the logical comparison for example:

```
if (*a > *b) return 1;
if (*a == *b) return 0;
if (*a < *b) return -1;
```