# Warning when using qsort in C

Tags: c, qsort

I wrote my comparison function

```
int cmp(const int * a,const int * b)
 {
   if (*a==*b)
   return 0;
else
  if (*a < *b)
    return -1;
else
    return 1;
}
```

and i have my declaration

```
int cmp (const int * value1,const int * value2);
```

and I'm calling qsort in my program like so

```
qsort(currentCases,round,sizeof(int),cmp);
```

when i compile it I get the following warning

```
warning: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdlib.h:710: note: expected ‘__compar_fn_t’ but argument is of type ‘int
(*)(const int *, const int *)’
```

The program works just fine so my only concern is why it doesn't like the way im using that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228695/what-are-the-parameters-in-this-c-qsort-function-call/2228754#2228754

Comment: Just a suggestion for a simpler implementation of your cmp; rather than the if/else stuff you could just use subtraction.

Comment: @nategoose: Not unless you want to introduce nasty integer overflow bugs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `cmp` function's prototype must be

```
int cmp(const void* a, const void* b);
```

You can either cast it in the invocation of qsort (not recommended):

```
qsort(currentCases, round, sizeof(int), (int(*)(const void*,const void*))cmp);
```

or casts the void-pointers to int-pointers in cmp (the standard approach):

```
int cmp(const void* pa, const void* pb) {
   int a = *(const int*)pa;
   int b = *(const int*)pb;
   ...
```

Comment: Technically the first is undefined behavior. There is no guarantee that your implementation's calling convention passes a `const int*` the same way it passes a `const void*`. In practice, I expect it'll be fine. Apparently GCC expects that too since it's only a warning.

Comment: The approach with cast is completely unacceptable, even if it might seem to "work".

Comment: @AndreyT: What else do you suggest? Write your own quick sort? (Note that this is C, not C++, you cannot use `std::sort`.)

Comment: @KennyTM: I think AndreyT meant the cast in the first approach in your answer, not the second.  For the second, you can of course do `int *the_a = pa; int a = *the_a;` etc., which doesn't use a cast.

Comment: @KennyTM: What I suggest is using the cast on the parameters, as you did in your second suggection. This is the only way to do it.

Comment: @AndreyT: I see. Because both methods involve casting ^_^.

Comment: Long story short: Casting function pointer types = evil, casting other types = less evil

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page, a `__compar_fn_t` is defined as: `typedef int(*) __compar_fn_t (const void *, const void *)`

Your `cmp` specifies `int*` parameters. It doesn't like that, but is only listed as a warning.

Comment: Thats because void* can be implicitly cast to any other type of pointer. in C at least, C++ has some issues with it.

Comment: Which man page are you looking at? The one for `qsort` does not mention `__compar_fn_t`