# qsort with typedef structs in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef, qsort

After searching in lots of posts, I cannot solve my problem. I want to order an array of structs depending on one field (deadline):

```
typedef struct{
    int ident;
    int computation;
    int period;
    int deadline;
}task_t;
task_t *tasks;

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {

        task_t *ia = *(task_t**)a;
        task_t *ib = *(task_t**)b;
        //task_t *ia = (task_t *)a;
        //task_t *ib = (task_t *)b;

        return (ia->deadline - ib->deadline);
}

//Randomly generation of parameters of tasks

fprintf(stderr,"before:\n");
    for (i=0;i<nT;i++){
            fprintf(stderr,"%d;%d;%d;%d\n", tasks[i].ident, tasks[i].computation, tasks[i].deadline,tasks[i].period);
        }

size_t size = sizeof(tasks) / sizeof(task_t*);

qsort(tasks, size, sizeof(task_t *), compare);


    fprintf(stderr,"\after:\n");
    for (i=0;i<nT;i++){
            fprintf(stderr,"%d;%d;%d;%d\n", tasks[i].ident, tasks[i].computation, tasks[i].deadline,tasks[i].period);
        }
```

Before and after qsort, the result is the same. I think the problem is the pointer but I don't know how to solve it. I have tried a lot of combinations qsort(&tasks, size, sizeof(task_t *), &compare);
and also inside compare function, but the result does not change. Could you help me? Sorry if the question is so many repeated.

Comment: I think is suppose to be `sizeof(task_t)` (without the pointer)

Comment: It's `task_t *ia = (task_t*)a;`, not `task_t *ia = *(task_t**)a;`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Even better:  `task_t *ia = a;` as no cast to/from `void *` is necessary in C.

Comment: Why are you using void* when your compare could just use the type of a and b ?  Your call to qsort is completely wrong.  tasks is a pointer to a number of elements to sort, your compare should take const tast_t* a, const task_t* b, internally forget the casting your compare a->deadline - b->deadline;

Comment: @רועיאבידן: Can't be `sizeof` at all, given `tasks` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @SPlatten: The required prototype for the `qsort` comparator takes `const void*` arguments. You can't pass a function that takes other arguments.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, why can't you just cast the call ?

Comment: @SPlatten: The standard doesn't require pointer compatibility like that. `void*` can be cast to any pointer, and vice versa, but only if it knows to cast; within `qsort` it "knows" the function takes `const void*` and will pass it as such, which would break when function itself doesn't expect `const void *`. [Full explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2228754/364696).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
size_t size = sizeof(tasks) / sizeof(task_t*);
```

only works if `tasks` is an array of `task_t*`. It isn't, it's a pointer to `task_t` (presumably to an array of `task_t`, but not one with compile-time size). You can't use `sizeof` in that case, you just have to know how big the array is in some other way. As is, you basically asked `qsort` to sort an array with one element in it.

You've also written your comparator wrong; if the array is of `task_t`s, then the `void*`s it receives are really pointers to `task_t`, not double pointers to `task_t`. So you'll need to change:

```
    task_t *ia = *(task_t**)a;
    task_t *ib = *(task_t**)b;
```

to:

```
    const task_t *ia = a;
    const task_t *ib = b;
```

Lastly, you need to pass `sizeof(task_t)` to `qsort`, not `sizeof(task_t *)`; again, the array is of `task_t`, not `task_t*`.

Comment: sizeof(task_t*) will give you the size of the pointer not the type.

Comment: @ryyker: It's arguable. `void*` will cast to any type without a cast in C, and it's definitely not idiomatic to cast it in some cases (e.g. [don't cast the return from `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/364696)). In this case, I can see it either way, but it's not necessary, so I went with the simplest form.

Comment: @SPlatten: Fixed (or more precisely, added; there were a lot of errors, and I didn't catch 'em all on first pass).