# Is it legal to cast function pointers?

Tags: c++, c, casting, function-pointers, void-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting a function pointer to another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type)

```
int primes[] = {11, 5, 3, 7, 19, 13, 2, 17};
int comp(const int*, const int*);
qsort(primes, 8, sizeof(int), (int(*)(const void*, const void*))comp);
```

Is the cast in the third line legal? Or must `comp` take `const void*` arguments and do the cast inside?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188839/function-pointer-cast-to-different-signature