# function pointer assignments

Tags: c, function, pointers

Why am I able to assign a function that returns an int with no parameters specified to a function pointer that returns an int but takes an int argument?

For example when I do:

```
int f()
{ return 0;}

int (*ptr)(int) = f;
```

the compiler gives me no warnings

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188839/function-pointer-cast-to-different-signature

Comment: Have you considered a C++ compiler to compile your C code?  Fixes this problem.

Comment: Another way to put it, I think, is "if you want that function pointer type to be inconsistent with that definition of `f`, then you could consider writing in C++ instead of C". But just taking your existing C code and trying to compile it as C++ has a number of problems - the rest of your code could fail to compile as C++, or fail to do the same thing in C++ as it did in C, for a host of other reasons, many of which are not bugs in the C code at all.

Comment: Not to mention all the cool C99 features that C++ disallows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, `f` doesn't take "no arguments", but rather "any arguments"*. Say `int f(void)` to declare "no arguments".

<sub>This is different from C++. Notably, C has separate notions of function "declaration" and function "prototype":</sub>

```
int f();              /* declaration -- f is still a mystery */
int f(int, double);   /* prototype -- now we know how to call f */
int f(int n, double c) { return -1; }  /* defintion -- now we can link */
```

*) As I said in the comment, "any arguments" is restricted to types that do not suffer default-promotion (in the same way as default-promotion happens to variadic arguments). That is, `float`, all flavours of `char` and of `short int`, and also `...`, are *not* permissible in the actual function signature.

Comment: int (*fptr)(char) = f;

gives me the warning: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type, though?

Comment: so i take it this is just compiler specific rather than language?

Comment: @user1079578: Wait, sorry, my other comment was wrong. You mustn't use types that are default-promotable. That is, `char`, `short int` and `float` are out. Think variadics!

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler do you use?

- MinGW-GCC-3.4.2: `invalid conversion from`int (*)()' to `int (*)(int)'`
- Visual Studio 2010 Pro: `Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int)'`

Comment: gcc 4.5.2 with default configuration