# How to print the address of a function?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, function-pointers, gcc-warning

I let `gcc` compile the following example using `-Wall -pedantic`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("main: %p\n", main); /* line 5 */
  printf("main: %p\n", (void*) main); /* line 6 */

  return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
main.c:5: warning: format ‘%p’ expects type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)()’
main.c:6: warning: ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type
```

Line 5 made my change the code like in line 6.

What am I missing to remove the warning when printing a function's address?

Comment: Not sure if it's available to you, but you might investigate using register_printf_function to [define your own special format character and converter](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html#Customizing-Printf).

Comment: The issue is not that it's "dangerous". The issue is that the conversion is not defined by the C language, and thus can't be used in conforming C code. You could cast through an intermediate integer type (implementation-defined results) as long as you know one exists that can hold both function and object pointers).

Comment: @BobJarvis Do you have any idea how to get around `gcc` complaining about the newly introduced conversion type character (`warning: unknown conversion type character ‘P’ in format`) when compiling with option `-Wall`? But this also is another story ...

Comment: @R..: This is C. We do dangerous.

Comment: @alk: try adding the -Wno-format option after -Wall, which (if memory serves) will turn off printf/scanf format checking.

Comment: @BobJarvis If could do as you proposed, I'd not had to pose this orignal question ... |-}. Anyway I found this here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47781 telling me that what I'd liked to have does not (yet?) exist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is essentially the only portable way to print a function pointer.

```
size_t i;
int (*ptr_to_main)() = main;
for (i=0; i<sizeof ptr_to_main; i++)
    printf("%.2x", ((unsigned char *)&ptr_to_main)[i]);
putchar('\n');
```

Comment: I like this, although it's silently ignoring any endianess issues... ;-)

Comment: Trying to generalise this approach, I wonder if function pointers of different types are guaranteed to have the same size, although an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/189126/694576) to the question referenced by larsman makes me doubt this ... - anyway this is another story though.

Comment: Conversion between any two functions pointers is defined and is round-trip-value-preserving, per the C standard; see the end of 6.3.2.3.

Comment: I would cast once, outside the loop, but this is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had originally misread OP's question as using the address of `printf`, and forgot to fix one reference. :-)

Comment: @R.. Did I miss someting, but how is that portable? You still are converting a function pointer (`&ptr_to_main`) to an object pointer type (`unsigned char *`) but C does not allow conversions between function pointer types and object pointer types.

Comment: @ouah: Indeed you missed something.  `ptr_to_main` is an object, and `&ptr_to_main` is an object pointer.

Comment: This assumes `CHAR_BIT==8`. With `CHAR_BIT > 8`, it will still print the full value of each byte, but the output can be ambiguous; `12345` could be either `12:345` or `123:45`. (This is practically never an issue.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson  Could use `printf("%.*x", (CHAR_BIT+3)/4, ((unsigned char *)&ptr_to_main)[i]);`  This avoids the magic number 2.

Answer (score 6):

This whole idea is indeed non-portable, since some systems use different sized pointers to code and data.

What you really need is platform-specific knowledge of how big a function pointer is, and a cast to an integral type of that size.  Unfortunately, I don't think anyone has standardized a `intfuncptr_t` analagous to `intptr_t` which can hold any data pointer.

---

As R. notes [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933437/103167), you can always treat the pointer as an array of (possibly `signed` or `unsigned`) `char`, this way you don't need any integral type of the correct size.

Comment: Not any integral data type; only `unsigned char` (or probably `char` tho that's messy and iffy). Any other type is an aliasing violation and modern compilers are likely to emit bad code that doesn't do what you wanted it to.

Comment: @R..: A conversion can't be an aliasing violation.  Only if you have two lvalues of different type referring to the same location, can there be an aliasing violation.  Note that I'm talking about `reinterpret_cast<integral_type>(fnptr)`, not `*reinterpret_cast<integral_type*>(&fnptr)`.  Your answer involves legal aliasing, mine involves no aliasing at all.  Oh, now I see, you're talking about my explanation of your method.  Yes, `char` is needed there, I'll update.

Comment: There is `(uintmax_t)&main`, perhaps with a `static_assert( sizeof(uintmax_t) >= sizeof(&main) );` to hopefully ensure no undiagnosed UB due to out-of-range conversion

Comment: Re: "you can always treat the pointer as an array ...": can you please point out the place in the C standard where it is said?

Comment: FYI: relevant to "you can always treat the pointer as an array ...": "Variables must be accessed through their declared type or through a pointer to a character type" ([source](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2016/08/17/effective-types-and-aliasing/)).

Answer (score 5):

It's right there in the warning: ISO C forbids conversion of a function pointer to an object pointer type, which includes `void*`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188839/function-pointer-cast-to-different-signature).

<del>You simply can't print the address of a function in a portable way, so you can't get rid of the warning.</del>

You can print a function pointer using @R..'s suggestion.

Comment: Per POSIX, the representation of all pointers is the same, so on a POSIX system, you can `memcpy` from a function pointer variable to a data pointer variable and then print that. And of course you can *always* print the representation of any type byte-by-byte, with no POSIX dependency.

Answer (score 4):

While converting a function pointer to a void pointer is technically dangerous, converting function pointers to void pointers is used in the POSIX standard, so it is almost sure to work on most compilers.

Look up `dlsym()`.

Comment: The majority of C code runs outside a POSIX-compliant environment.

Comment: Assigning `dlsym()`'s return value to a properly declared function pointer variable leads to a similar issue, but the other way round.

Comment: So, basically, POSIX-2001 is incompatible with ABI definitions that use a different size for function pointers than for a `void*`. Nice to know.