# Address of function main() in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

Is there a way to find out the address of **main()** in C or C++ ?
Since it is itself a function ,would there be an address of it own ?

Comment: The main function is considered special in that it has a variety of limitations. One of them is that its address cannot be taken. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function has more detail.

Comment: *"Is there a way to find out the address of main() in C/C++ ?"* The phrase "in C/C++" is usually meaningless; ask about C, or C++. They've diverged wildly.

Comment: Why do you ask? On which operating system? With which compiler?

Comment: You can have the compiler print out a *map* file which will show the addresses of all the functions.

Comment: Which compiler? Which platform?  Some compilers have functions you can call to get addresses of functions.  On some compilers, there is a command file that provides the starting address of the `main` function (such as with embedded systems).

Answer (score 18):

#### C

Sure. Simply go ahead and do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("%p\n", &main);
}
```

---

#### C++

It is not permitted to take `main`'s address so, for your purposes, there isn't one:

> `[C++11: 3.6.1/3]:` The function main shall not be used within a program. *[..]*

However, in GCC you can take the same approach as you would in C, via a compiler extension:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << (void*)&main << '\n';
}
```

You will receive a warning that this is not compliant.

Comment: The question is wrongly tagged as both C and C++. This answer is correct for C++, but incorrect for C.

Comment: _"It is not permitted to take main's address so, for all intents and purposes"_ Not even for printing it out?

Comment: Unfortunately, that example in C has undefined behaviour. `%p` takes `void *`, not `int (*)(void)`. There's no portable way of printing a function pointer, there's no portable way of converting between object and function pointers.

Comment: So ,are you trying to say C++'s main() function can return its address to the user but C can't !!

Comment: @user3619236: C++'s main() function does not "return its address to the user".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think the question is worth answering. But if you are going to answer it anyway, you might as well do it right. :)

Comment: @hvd: There is a way to portable print the address of a function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10933437/694576

Comment: @alk What that prints isn't the address of a function, but the representation of an address of a function. Which, admittedly, for practical purposes, is just as good, so I should've mentioned that. Thanks.

Comment: @alk: Good point -- but the code in that answer (which breaks down the address into bytes and prints it using `printf("%.2x", ...)`) can in principle produce ambiguous output if `CHAR_BIT > 8`. The `2` implicitly assumes 2 4-bit values per byte; it will print the entire byte value, but if the value exceeds `0xff` it can be impossible to tell where one byte ends and another begins. In practice, this is almost never an issue.

Comment: ISO C does allow `void *p; *(int (**)(void)(&p) = main;`. If `sizeof (void *) == sizeof (int (*)(void))`, this and the inverse work: it is the *storage* *representation* that is copied. This is the workaround POSIX.1-2003 and POSIX.1-2008 folks proposed, for example for the inverse cases such as [`dlsym()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html). Casting void pointers to function pointers is an optional extension in C99 and C11, and POSIX.1-2013 requires that conforming implementations support that extension.

Comment: @NominalAnimal ISO C doesn't allow that, it's a violation of the aliasing rules and at least some versions of GCC will optimise based on the assumption that you don't write code like that. POSIX does add guarantees beyond what C allows, but are you sure this particular form is covered by one of those guarantees? (Note: examples aren't normative. I'm aware of the example in the description of `dlsym`.) I think only `p = (void *) main;` is covered by it. See 2.12.3 Pointer types.

Comment: @hvd: I don't see how aliasing rules would be broken by `*(int (**)(void))(&p) = main;`. If a C99/C11/later compiler treats the two expressions differently, I claim the compiler is buggy. I don't know of any GCC version (or flag or optimization) that would make GCC do that. Care to prove me wrong? (POSIX.1-2013 requires the compiler to support `void *p = main;`. Earlier, it was just a suggested workaround. Like I said, I claim ISO C99/C11 does allow the expression, so no reason to rely on POSIX; they just recommended the expression as a workaround.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal I referred to 2.12.3 Pointer types, and that explicitly mentions such conversions must be supported "using an explicit cast" (those are the exact words). An implicit conversion is an error just as it always was. As for `*(int (**)(void))(&p) = main;`, it's a violation of the aliasing rules, C99 6.5p7, that describe in which circumstances an object may be accessed by an incompatible type. That doesn't allow a distinct pointer type, and neither does POSIX. GCC 4.5 warns (`-O2 -Wall`): "warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules".

Comment: @NominalAnimal And it's easy to come up with an example where it breaks: [this example](http://ideone.com/1SlVmq) returns zero with later GCC versions, but one with GCC 4.5. If you think that's a conformance issue that got fixed in later versions, I'd be happy to read whatever standard it failed to conform to, but as far as I can tell, returning 1 is perfectly valid in all versions of C and all versions of POSIX.

Comment: @hvd: Using GCC 4.4.7, the example returns zero, although GCC claims your example breaks strict-aliasing rules (probably bug 41874). GCC 4.6.4 and later do not complain, but return zero too. It is GCC 4.5 that behaves differently to versions prior or after (and a version I have skipped myself). Anyway, if one were to agree with you, the workaround is to use `void *p; int (*f)(void) = main; memcpy(&p, &f, sizeof f);`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal GCC 4.4.7 returns one too, if optimisations are enabled (`-O2`, like I mentioned I used with GCC 4.5). So do 4.3.6, 4.2.4, 4.1.2, 4.0.4, 3.4.6 and 3.3.6. It's not like 4.5 suddenly changed this. It doesn't look like the bug you refer to: there really is an aliasing problem in my sample program. You're right that `memcpy` is a valid workaround: that too isn't supported by ISO C (since it doesn't require the same representations for different pointer types, and even allows `sizeof p != sizeof f`), but it's guaranteed by POSIX.

Comment: @hvd: GCC 4.4.7 returns zero with `-O1` or `-O2 -fno-strict-aliasing`. Personally, I rely on the compiler to handle `void *p; p = main;` (C99/C11 optional extension J.5.7, also POSIX.1-2013), `void *p; *(int (**)(void))(&p) = main;`, and `void *p; { int (*f)(void) = main; memcpy(&p, &f, sizeof f);` the exact same way. Even if I am wrong about ISO C99/C11 compliance, all three **must** produce the same `p` (or not compile), or a buttload of C code (including code written to POSIX.1-2003/-2008 suggestions) will miscompile. One of these must work for polymorphic function pointers (e.g. dlsym()).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71116/discussion-between-hvd-and-nominal-animal).

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit:  your C example is not quite correct:  in C, the name of a function is a pointer to the function, so you should use main instead of &main in the printf call.

Comment: My previous comment was not quite correct-- using g++, both main and @main give the same result.

Comment: @JeffBuck: `g++` compiles C++, not C (although if your file extension is `.c` then you'll still get away with it). Anyway, `&main` is the same as `main` in this context, but better expresses intent. As always, I tested and verified both snippets before posting this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't 100% sure whether the question was meant from within a program using C/++ or to retrieve address of the `main()` function created with C/C++ (meaning from the command line).

Since it looks like you've received several good answers on how to get the address from within the program, I thought I'd mention you can get this info from `nm` as well.

```
nm program|grep main
```

Answer (score 1):

If for any system you can't find the address of main.. put an invocation to a function foo() as the only statement in main, have main return whatever it returns and use the address of foo rather than main.

Note that calling main won't necessarily restart your code, even if there are no static/global variables.  The compiler generates start up code before actually calling main.

If you want to breakpoint before this call to main write something like:

```
static int i=foo();
```

and foo will be called during the earlier data initialisation step.