# write(), printf(), and function references in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

A few questions about this simple scenario:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void empty(){};

int main()
{
    printf("%p\t%lu\n", empty, sizeof(empty));
    write(1, empty, 100);

    return 0;
}
```

What exactly is happening when I use the function's name as a reference?

It shows size of one but printf still treats it as a pointer and yet a void pointer is of size 8. Additionally, onto the write function:

Essentially I want to replicate the printf %p writing the value of a memory address rather than the value at that address mainly to get a better handle on how this all works :^)

Thanks!

Comment: Function pointers are special that way, don't treat them as normal pointers.

Comment: `%p` formats a `void*` pointer. Function pointers can’t be safely cast to `void*`, so you’re using `printf` wrong and it doesn’t actually work. You also can’t use `sizeof` on function pointers: [“The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type” (6.5.3.4)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: A `long long` also most times has a size of `8`. Still different types. What is the point?

Comment: C11 says (§6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators): _Constraints:
The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an
incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that
designates a bit-field member._  Compiling with GCC and `-pedantic`, I get: `pedantic.c:9:46: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a function type [-Werror=pointer-arith]`.  Incidentally, `write()` is declared in `<unistd.h>`, not `<fcntl.h>`.

Comment: @minitech so what value is it printing?

Comment: @Olaf It being a pointer and returning void I thought there'd be some correlation. Irregardless I was only confused.

Comment: On most machines, `sizeof(void (*)(void)) == sizeof(void *)`, so the compiler makes a conversion and prints a value which is more or less OK.  There are systems (IBM AS/400, which are now call iSeries, IIRC) where that is not the case — a function pointer is 128 bits, but ordinary pointers are only 64 bits.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Alright that provides some clarity. I definitely need to read the standard and continue experimenting. Thanks again.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10932910/694576