# Function pointer returning a pointer of some type in C

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, c99

I am having trouble solving this below piece of code.

When i compile the entire file with this below piece of code included, i see a warning ( shown below), which i don't see if excluded from the entire *.c file.

**CODE:**

```
int * ( * get_ptr1)(int) = (int* )0x234456;
printf("The address of the func_ptr is %x\n", get_ptr1);
```

**Warning message:**

```
Initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Could anyone please explain me why i am seeing this warning and what need to be corrected in the above code. I am using a C99 standard compiler.

Please bear with me if my title is not very specific to what i have asked.

Comment: `int * ( * get_ptr1)(int) = (int* )0x234456;` - what do you expect this line to do?

Comment: i am trying to provide address 0x234456 to the function pointer. I saw this piece of code in a linux kernal and i was tring to understand its functionality. I would appreciate if you could explain me this with some different examples.

Comment: a `int* (*)(int)` is not a `int*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int *` and `int *(*)(int)` are different types. You could write:

```
int *(*get_ptr1)(int) = (int *(*)(int))0x234456;
```

There is no format specifier for function pointers with `printf`. Your use of `%x` causes undefined behaviour. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932910/how-to-print-the-address-of-a-function) for some ideas.

Comment: Regarding the printf issue, casting the function pointer to an integer type could also be an option.

Comment: @M.M In standard C, as per 6.3.2.3/6. But it could invoke implementation-defined behavior, unless you use `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @Lundin OK, although it may also invoke UB (as per 6.3.2.3/6), even for `uintptr_t` which is only guaranteed to be able to hold object pointer values (7.20.1.4)