# Output address of variable without printf %p

Tags: c, printf

I am a first year student in C programming so my skill/knowledge is limited. I am trying to create my own implementation on `printf`,  but I am having trouble with retrieving and printing the address of a variable. With `printf`, its possible to output the address of a variable with `%p`,  i need to replicate `%p` somehow.

When storing the address of a variable, the data type is `int*`, and I cannot figure out how to write this address to the screen(stdout).

### For Example:

```
int i        = 123;
int *address = &i;
```

Now how would I output `address`(not the value at `i`)?  I have tried using the original `printf` format specifiers for testing purposes. I tried using %x, %s, %d, %lu... it all gives me an error as I am trying to output an `int*`(integer pointer).

Can anyone assist me in outputting the address?

Comment: @Anders K. This will cut the upper 32bit of a 64bit address on a 64bit machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's for the address of an object you could do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a;
  uintptr_t uip = (uintptr_t) ((void*) &a);
  printf("address of a = 0x%"PRIXPTR, uip);
}
```

To print the address of a function you need to go [as proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933437/694576).

Comment: I didn't find anything that would prohibit casting function pointers to uintptr_t. Did I miss something?

Comment: I already did: *Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type.* Since a distinction is made in other rules between object and function pointer types, I think *any pointer type* applies to both.

Comment: @2502: Ok, got it: `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are guaranteed by the Standard only to hold the value of  a valid `void*` (7.20.1.4/1). A function may not be converted to a `void*`.

Comment: @2501: Sry, for misspelling your name. Interesting typo however ... ;-)

Comment: So I deduce: Casting to void* previously is obsolete and you simply could have `(uintptr_t) &a;`...

Comment: @Aconcagua: "*Casting to void\* previously is obsolete*" it isn't. Please see my comment above quoting the C Standard.

Comment: @alk I deduced from 2501 citation: *"Any pointer type may be [...]"* - the void* part in your comment is in my eyes rather a size guarantee: It can hold a valid void*, thus can hold any other valid pointer, too, as long as it is convertible to void* (and thus excludes function pointers).

Answer (score 5):

You can only inspect the bits of the pointer and print those, using the type unsigned char:

```
unsigned char* a = ( unsigned char* )address;
for( size_t i = 0 ; i < sizeof( address ) ; i++ )
     printf( "%hhu" , a[i] );
```

Another option, if the pointer is a pointer to an object, is to cast the pointer to types: `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, but the availability of those types is implementation defined.

Comment: They should be available since C99.

Comment: @Aconcagua Those types are optional, thus it depends on the implementation.