# Dynamic Libraries, plugin frameworks, and function pointer casting in c++

Tags: c++, plugins, frameworks, function-pointers, dynamic-library

I am trying to create a very open plugin framework in c++, and it seems to me that I have come up with a way to do so, but a nagging thought keeps telling me that there is something very, very wrong with what I am doing, and it either won't work or it will cause problems.

The design I have for my framework consists of a Kernel that calls each plugin's `init` function. The init function then turns around and uses the Kernel's `registerPlugin` and `registerFunction` to get a unique id and then register each function the plugin wants to be accessible using that id, respectively.

The function registerPlugin returns the unique id. The function registerFunction takes that id, the function name, and a generic function pointer, like so:

```
bool registerFunction(int plugin_id, string function_name, plugin_function func){}
```

where plugin_function is

```
typedef void (*plugin_function)();
```

The kernel then takes the function pointer and puts it in a map with the `function_name` and `plugin_id`. All plugins registering their function must caste the function to type `plugin_function`.

In order to retrieve the function, a different plugin calls the Kernel's

```
plugin_function getFunction(string plugin_name, string function_name);
```

Then that plugin must cast the `plugin_function` to its original type so it can be used. It knows (in theory) what the correct type is by having access to a `.h` file outlining all the functions the plugin makes available. Plugins, by the by, are implemented as dynamic libraries.

Is this a smart way to accomplish the task of allowing different plugins to connect with each other? Or is this a crazy and really terrible programming technique? If it s, please point me in the direction of the correct way to accomplish this.

EDIT: If any clarification is needed, ask and it will be provided.

Comment: Have you considered exposing a C API (I notice you have C++'s `string` in there)? It would avoid some problems with developers using different compilers/flags than yours for compiling their DLL. Also, how does the plugin cast the pointer back to the right type? Why not just use a fixed function signature (avoiding casting altogether)? Finally, in general not all function pointers are all the same size, but I think all free-function pointers are (not sure about cross-compiler size, though).

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you would go into more depth and post this as an answer. My knowledge of c++, function pointers, and using dynamic libraries comes from fractured tutorials and articles across the internet. I have done the best I can to piece it together and make something usable, but I don't think it is the best solution, hence this question.

Comment: How much have you looked at already-existing plugin frameworks? Qt, dbus, COM+, etc?

Comment: I have looked at various frameworks, mainly Qt. It seemed to me that dbus is mostly about cross-application connections and COM+ is miscrosoft-specific. Qt looked interesting, but I got tired of trying to find simple (or at least reasonably uncomplex) documentation on what it is and how to use it. Everything I have found has either been way too general (explaining what a dynamic library is) or way to specific (explaining the code) and there doesn't seem to be anything in between (explaining the design and interactions of the framework).

Comment: I think the only pointer type that's guaranteed by the standard to be safe for a round-trip cast is `void *`. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the standard to quote that for you.

Comment: It's slightly bit-rotted now (e.g. it doesn't use `std::function`), but the proposed [Boost.Extension](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/index.html) looks like a good direction to think about.

Comment: @MirroredFate: Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner, but I thought it would take a while to answer (which it did), but I hope it clarifies some stuff. I learnt 95% of this stuff from fractured tutorials and articles on the internet, by the way ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Function pointers are strange creatures. They're not necessarily the same size as data pointers, and hence cannot be safely cast to `void*` and back. But, the C++ (and C) specifications allow [any function pointer to be safely cast to another function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11240372/21475) type (though you have to later cast it back to the earlier type before calling it if you want defined behaviour). This is akin to the ability to safely cast any data pointer to `void*` and back.

Pointers to methods are where it gets really hairy: a method pointer might be larger than a normal function pointer, depending on the compiler, whether the application is 32- or 64-bit, etc. But even more interesting is that, even on the same compiler/platform, not all method pointers are the same size: Method pointers to virtual functions may be bigger than normal method pointers; if multiple inheritance (with e.g. virtual inheritance in the diamond pattern) is involved, the method pointers can be even bigger. This varies with compiler and platform too. This is also the reason that it's difficult to create function objects (that wrap arbitrary methods as well as free functions) especially without allocating memory on the heap (it's *just* possible using [template sorcery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4300544/21475)).

So, by using function pointers in your interface, it becomes unpractical for the plugin authors to pass back method pointers to your framework, even if they're using the same compiler. This might be an acceptable constraint; more on this later.

Since there's no guarantee that function pointers will be the same size from one compiler to the next, by registering function pointers you're limiting the plugin authors to compilers that implement function pointers having the same size as your compiler does. This wouldn't necessarily be so bad in practice, since function pointer sizes tend to be stable across compiler versions (and may even be the same for multiple compilers).

The real problems start to arise when you want to call the functions pointed to by the function pointers; you can't safely call the function at all if you don't know its true signature (you *will* get poor results ranging from "not working" to segmentation faults). So, the plugin authors would be further limited to registering only `void` functions that take no parameters.

It gets worse: the way a function call actually works at the assembler level depends on more than just the signature and function pointer size. There's also the calling convention, the way exceptions are handled (the stack needs to be properly unwound when an exception is thrown), and the actual interpretation of the bytes of function pointer (if it's larger than a data pointer, what do the extra bytes signify? In what order?). At this point, the plugin author is pretty much limited to using the same compiler (and version!) that you are, and needs to be careful to match the calling convention and exception handling options (with the MSVC++ compiler, for example, exception handling is only explicitly enabled with the [`/EHsc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option), as well as use only normal function pointers with the exact signature you define.

All the restrictions so far *can* be considered reasonable, if a bit limiting. But we're not done yet.

If you throw in `std::string` (or almost any part of the STL), things get even worse though, because even with the same compiler (and version), there are several different flags/macros that control the STL; these flags can affect the size and meaning of the bytes representing string objects. It is, in effect, like having two *different* struct declarations in separate files, each with the same name, and hoping they'll be interchangeable; obviously, this doesn't work. An example flag is `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`. Note that these options can even change between debug and release mode! These types of errors don't always manifest themselves immediately/consistently and can be very difficult to track down.

You also have to be very careful with dynamic memory management across modules, since `new` in one project may be defined differently from `new` in another project (e.g. it may be overloaded). When deleting, you might have a pointer to an interface with a virtual destructor, meaning the `vtable` is needed to properly `delete` the object, and different compilers all implement the `vtable` stuff differently. In general, you want the module that allocates an object to be the one to deallocate it; more specifically, you want the *code* that deallocates an object to have been compiled under the exact same conditions as the code that allocated it. This is one reason `std::shared_ptr` can take a "deleter" argument when it is constructed -- because even with the same compiler and flags (the only guaranteed safe way to share `shared_ptr`s between modules), `new` and `delete` may not be the same everywhere the `shared_ptr` can get destroyed. With the deleter, the code that creates the shared pointer controls how it is eventually destroyed too. (I just threw this paragraph in for good measure; you don't seem to be sharing objects across module boundaries.)

All of this is a consequence of C++ having no standard binary interface ([ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492180/c-abi-issues-list)); it's a free-for-all, where it is very easy to shoot yourself in the foot (sometimes without realising it).

So, is there any hope? You betcha! You can expose a C API to your plugins instead, and have your plugins also expose a C API. This is quite nice because a C API can be interoperated with from virtually any language. You don't have to worry about exceptions, apart from making sure they can't bubble up above the plugin functions (that's the authors' concern), and it's stable no matter the compiler/options (assuming you don't pass STL containers and the like). There's only one standard calling convention (`cdecl`), which is the default for functions declared `extern "C"`. `void*`, in practice, will be the same across all compilers on the same platform (e.g. 8 bytes on x64).

You (and the plugin authors) can still write your code in C++, as long as all the external communication between the two uses a C API (i.e. pretends to be a C module for the purposes of interop).

C function pointers are also likely compatible between compilers in practice, though if you'd rather not depend on this you could have the plugin register a function *name* (`const char*`) instead of address, and then you could extract the address yourself using, e.g., [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows (similarly, Linux and Mac OS X have `dlopen` and `dlsym`). This works because [name-mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work) is disabled for functions declared with `extern "C"`.

Note that there's no direct way around restricting the registered functions to be of a single prototype type (otherwise, as I've said, you can't call them properly). If you need to give a particular parameter to a plugin function (or get a value back), you'll need to register and call the different functions with different prototypes separately (though you could collapse all the function pointers down to a common function pointer type internally, and only cast back at the last minute).

Finally, while you cannot directly support method pointers (which don't even exist in a C API, but are of variable size even with a C++ API and thus cannot be easily stored), you can allow the plugins to supply a "user-data" opaque pointer when registering their function, which is passed to the function whenever it's called; this gives the plugin authors an easy way to write function wrappers around methods and store the object to apply the method to in the user-data parameter. The user-data parameter can also be used for anything else the plugin author wants, which makes your plugin system much easier to interface with and extend. Another example use is to adapt between different function prototypes using a wrapper and extra arguments stored in the user-data.

These suggestions lead to code something like this (for Windows -- the code is very similar for other platforms):

```
// Shared header
extern "C" {
    typedef void (*plugin_function)(void*);

    bool registerFunction(int plugin_id, const char* function_name, void* user_data);
}

// Your plugin registration code
hModule = LoadLibrary(pluginDLLPath);

// Your plugin function registration code
auto pluginFunc = (plugin_function)GetProcAddress(hModule, function_name);
// Store pluginFunc and user_data in a map keyed to function_name

// Calling a plugin function
pluginFunc(user_data);

// Declaring a plugin function
extern "C" void aPluginFunction(void*);
class Foo { void doSomething() { } };

// Defining a plugin function
void aPluginFunction(void* user_data)
{
    static_cast<Foo*>(user_data)->doSomething();
}
```

Sorry for the length of this reply; most of it can be summed up with "the C++ standard doesn't extend to interoperation; use C instead since it at least has *de facto* standards."

---

Note: Sometimes it's simplest just to design a normal C++ API (with function pointers or interfaces or whatever you like best) under the assumption that the plugins will be compiled under exactly the same circumstances; this is reasonable if you expect all the plugins to be developed by yourself (i.e. the DLLs are part of the project core). This could also work if your project is open-source, in which case everybody can independently choose a cohesive environment under which the project and the plugins are compiled -- but then this makes it hard to distribute plugins except as source code.

---

**Update**: As pointed out by ern0 in the comments, it's possible to abstract the details of the module interoperation (via a C API) so that both the main project and the plugins deal with a simpler C++ API. What follows is an outline of such an implementation:

```
// iplugin.h -- shared between the project and all the plugins
class IPlugin {
public:
    virtual void register() { }
    virtual void initialize() = 0;

    // Your application-specific functionality here:
    virtual void onCheeseburgerEatenEvent() { }
};

// C API:
extern "C" {
    // Returns the number of plugins in this module
    int getPluginCount();

    // Called to register the nth plugin of this module.
    // A user-data pointer is expected in return (may be null).
    void* registerPlugin(int pluginIndex);

    // Called to initialize the nth plugin of this module
    void initializePlugin(int pluginIndex, void* userData);

    void onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent(int pluginIndex, void* userData);
}


// pluginimplementation.h -- plugin authors inherit from this abstract base class
#include "iplugin.h"
class PluginImplementation {
public:
    PluginImplementation();
};


// pluginimplementation.cpp -- implements C API of plugin too
#include <vector>

struct LocalPluginRegistry {
    static std::vector<PluginImplementation*> plugins;
};

PluginImplementation::PluginImplementation() {
    LocalPluginRegistry::plugins.push_back(this);
}

extern "C" {
    int getPluginCount() {
        return static_cast<int>(LocalPluginRegistry::plugins.size());
    }

    void* registerPlugin(int pluginIndex) {
        auto plugin = LocalPluginRegistry::plugins[pluginIndex];
        plugin->register();
        return (void*)plugin;
    }

    void initializePlugin(int pluginIndex, void* userData) {
        auto plugin = static_cast<PluginImplementation*>(userData);
        plugin->initialize();
    }

    void onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent(int pluginIndex, void* userData) {
        auto plugin = static_cast<PluginImplementation*>(userData);
        plugin->onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent();
    }
}


// To declare a plugin in the DLL, just make a static instance:
class SomePlugin : public PluginImplementation {
    virtual void initialize() {  }
};
SomePlugin plugin;    // Will be created when the DLL is first loaded by a process


// plugin.h -- part of the main project source only
#include "iplugin.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

class PluginRegistry;

class Plugin : public IPlugin {
public:
    Plugin(PluginRegistry* registry, int index, int moduleIndex)
        : registry(registry), index(index), moduleIndex(moduleIndex)
    {
    }

    virtual void register();
    virtual void initialize();

    virtual void onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent();

private:
    PluginRegistry* registry;
    int index;
    int moduleIndex;
    void* userData;
};

class PluginRegistry {
public:
    registerPluginsInModule(std::string const& modulePath);
    ~PluginRegistry();

public:
    std::vector<Plugin*> plugins;

private:
    extern "C" {
        typedef int (*getPluginCountFunc)();
        typedef void* (*registerPluginFunc)(int);
        typedef void (*initializePluginFunc)(int, void*);
        typedef void (*onCheeseBurgerEatenEventFunc)(int, void*);
    }

    struct Module {
        getPluginCountFunc getPluginCount;
        registerPluginFunc registerPlugin;
        initializePluginFunc initializePlugin;
        onCheeseBurgerEatenEventFunc onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent;

        HMODULE handle;
    };

    friend class Plugin;
    std::vector<Module> registeredModules;
}


// plugin.cpp
void Plugin::register() {
    auto func = registry->registeredModules[moduleIndex].registerPlugin;
    userData = func(index);
}

void Plugin::initialize() {
    auto func = registry->registeredModules[moduleIndex].initializePlugin;
    func(index, userData);
}

void Plugin::onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent() {
    auto func = registry->registeredModules[moduleIndex].onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent;
    func(index, userData);
}

PluginRegistry::registerPluginsInModule(std::string const& modulePath) {
    // For Windows:
    HMODULE handle = LoadLibrary(modulePath.c_str());

    Module module;
    module.handle = handle;
    module.getPluginCount = (getPluginCountFunc)GetProcAddr(handle, "getPluginCount");
    module.registerPlugin = (registerPluginFunc)GetProcAddr(handle, "registerPlugin");
    module.initializePlugin = (initializePluginFunc)GetProcAddr(handle, "initializePlugin");
    module.onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent = (onCheeseBurgerEatenEventFunc)GetProcAddr(handle, "onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent");

    int moduleIndex = registeredModules.size();
    registeredModules.push_back(module);

    int pluginCount = module.getPluginCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < pluginCount; ++i) {
        auto plugin = new Plugin(this, i, moduleIndex);
        plugins.push_back(plugin);
    }
}

PluginRegistry::~PluginRegistry() {
    for (auto it = plugins.begin(); it != plugins.end(); ++it) {
        delete *it;
    }

    for (auto it = registeredModules.begin(); it != registeredModules.end(); ++it) {
        FreeLibrary(it->handle);
    }
}



// When discovering plugins (e.g. by loading all DLLs in a "plugins" folder):
PluginRegistry registry;
registry.registerPluginsInModule("plugins/cheeseburgerwatcher.dll");
for (auto it = registry.plugins.begin(); it != registry.plugins.end(); ++it) {
    (*it)->register();
}
for (auto it = registry.plugins.begin(); it != registry.plugins.end(); ++it) {
    (*it)->initialize();
}

// And then, when a cheeseburger is actually eaten:
for (auto it = registry.plugins.begin(); it != registry.plugins.end(); ++it) {
    auto plugin = *it;
    plugin->onCheeseBurgerEatenEvent();
}
```

This has the benefit of using a C API for compatibility, but also offering a higher level of abstraction for plugins written in C++ (and for the main project code, which is C++). Note that it lets multiple plugins be defined in a single DLL. You could also eliminate some of the duplication of function names by using macros, but I chose not to for this simple example.

---

All of this, by the way, assumes plugins that have no interdependencies -- if plugin A affects (or is required by) plugin B, you need to devise a safe method for injecting/constructing dependencies as needed, since there's no way of guaranteeing what order the plugins will be loaded in (or initialized). A two-step process would work well in that case: Load and register all plugins; during registration of each plugin, let them register any services they provide. During initialization, construct requested services as needed by looking at the registered service table. This ensures that all services offered by all plugins are registered *before* any of them are attempted to be used, no matter what order plugins get registered or initialized in.

Comment: +1 for mention of exposing a C API, STL warnings and shooting oneself in the foot (and taking off your whole leg?)

Comment: @nick_w: [Yes](http://www.stgray.com/quotes/cppquotes.html). Sometimes even the whole torso! ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for a good, well thought-out answer. I am going to go over it in depth and make sure I understand every piece, but after just reading it over once, it looks very promising.

Comment: @MirroredFate: Sure, no problem :-) If anything needs clarification/expansion, let me know.

Comment: Maybe, it's trivial, I'm just thinking aloud: if you don't wanna publish source code, you may provide a plugin base class, which implements all the C/C++ conversion tricks, so plugin writer has only to extend that class, to make plugin writers' life easier.

Comment: @ern0: That's a neat idea (and hadn't occurred to me), but you'd have to be careful to make sure the base class is never used directly from the main project (i.e. it would have to expose a C API, making things like multiple plugin class instances per DLL tricky, though entirely feasible).

Comment: Yep, the open-source base class is only for hiding the pain for the plugin writers - not for you.

Comment: @ern0: I really like that concept. Do you mind if I write some code using that idea in my answer, or would you prefer to submit your own answer?

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you. A plugin manifest file will solve that last problem.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you took is sane in general, but I see a few possible improvements.

- Your kernel should export C functions with a conventional calling convention (cdecl, or maybe stdcall if you are on Windows) for the registration of plugins and functions. If you use a C++ function then you are forcing all plugin authors to use the same compiler and compiler version that you use, since many things like C++ function name mangling, STL implementation and calling conventions are compiler specific.
- Plugins should only export C functions like the kernel.
- From the definition of `getFunction` it seems each plugin has a name, which other plugins can use to obtain its functions. This is not a safe practice, two developers can create two different plugins with the same name, so when a plugin asks for some other plugin by name it may get a different plugin than the expected one. A better solution would be for plugins to have a public [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier). This GUID can appear in each plugin's header file, so that other plugins can refer to it.
- You have not implemented versioning. Ideally you want your kernel to be versioned because invariably you will change it in the future. When a plugin registers with the kernel it passes the version of the kernel API it was compiled against. The kernel then can decide if the plugin can be loaded. For example, if kernel version 1 receives a registration request for a plugin that requires kernel version 2 you have a problem, the best way to address that is to not allow the plugin to load since it may need kernel features that are not present in the older version. The reverse case is also possible, kernel v2 may or may not want to load plugins that were created for kernel v1, and if it does allow it it may need to adapt itself to the older API.
- I'm not sure I like the idea of a plugin being able to locate another plugin and call its functions directly, as this breaks encapsulation. It seems better to me if plugins advertise their capabilities to the kernel, so that other plugins can find services they need by capability instead of by addressing other plugins by name or GUID.
- Be aware that any plugin that allocates memory needs to provide a deallocation function for that memory. Each plugin could be using a different run-time library, so memory allocated by a plugin may be unknown to other plugins or the kernel. Having allocation and deallocation in the same module avoids problems.

Comment: +1, especially for mentioning versioning and GUIDs. Excellent answer!

Comment: While I didn't choose this for the bounty, it has some excellent points and is very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). So what you want doing has a restriction: the plugins and your framework must compile & link by same compiler & linker with same parameter in same os. That is meaningless if the achievement is inter-operation in form of binary distribution because each plugin developed for framework has to prepare many version which target at different compiler on different os. So distrbute source code will be more practical than this and that's the way of GNU(download a src, configure and make)

COM is a chose, but it is too complex and out-of-date. Or managed C++ on .Net runtime. But they are only on ms os. If you want a universal solution, I suggest you change to another language.

Answer (score 1):

As jean mentions, since there is no standard C++ ABI and standard name mangling conventions you are stuck to compile things with same compiler and linker. If you want a shared library/dll kind of plugins you have to use something C-ish.

If all will be compiled with same compiler and linker, you may want to also consider std::function.

```
typedef std::function<void ()> plugin_function;

std::map<std::string, plugin_function> fncMap;

void register_func(std::string name, plugin_function fnc)
{
   fncMap[name] = fnc;
}

void call(std::string name)
{
   auto it = fncMap.find(name);
   if (it != fncMap.end())
      (it->second)();   // it->second is a function object
}


///////////////

void func()
{
   std::cout << "plain" << std::endl;
}

class T
{
public:
   void method()
   {
     std::cout << "method" << std::endl;
   }

   void method2(int i)
   {
     std::cout << "method2 : " << i << std::endl;
   }
};


T t; // of course "t" needs to outlive the map, you could just as well use shared_ptr

register_func("plain", func);
register_func("method", std::bind(&T::method, &t));
register_func("method2_5", std::bind(&T::method2, &t, 5));
register_func("method2_15", std::bind(&T::method2, &t, 15));

call("plain");
call("method");
call("method2_5");
call("method2_15");
```

You can also have plugin functions that take argumens. This will use the placeholders for std::bind, but soon you can find that it is somewhat lacking behind boost::bind. Boost bind has nice documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you should not do this. In C++ using this style of pointer is the best since it's just a plain pointer. I know of no popular compiler that would do anything as brain-dead as not making a function pointer like a normal pointer. It is beyond the bounds of reason that someone would do something so horrible.

The Vst plugin standard operates in a similar way. It just uses function pointers in the .dll and does not have ways of calling directly to classes. Vst is a very popular standard and on windows people use just about any compiler to do Vst plugins, including Delphi which is pascal based and has nothing to do with C++.

So I would do exactly what you suggest personally. For the common well-known plugins I would not use a string name but an integer index which can be looked up much faster.

The alternative is to use interfaces but I see no reason to if your thinking is already based around function pointers.

If you use interfaces then it is not so easy to call the functions from other languages. You can do it from Delphi but what about .NET.

With your function pointer style suggestion you can use .NET to make one of the plugins for example. Obviously you would need to host Mono in your program to load it but just for hypothetical purposes it illustrates the simplicity of it.

Besides, when you use interfaces you have to get into reference counting which is nasty. Stick your logic in function pointers like you suggest and then wrap the control in some C++ classes to do the calling and stuff for you. Then other people can make the plugins with other languages such as Delphi Pascal, Free Pascal, C, Other C++ compilers etc...

But as always, regardless of what you do, exception handling between compilers will remain an issue so you have to think about the error handling. Best way is that the plugins own method catches own plugin exceptions and returns an error code to the kernel etc...

Comment: +1 for interfaces, it's much easier to expose a single function and get allocated object back. That's pretty much how plugin systems implemented in many apps.

Comment: If you look at Vst, they use a very small number of functions and then use constants and some generic parameters to handle all the calls between plugins. Vst is not the best example but it functions alright for having plugins made with any compiler.

Answer (score 0):

With all the excellent answers above, I'll just add that this practice is actually pretty wide distributed. In my practice, I've seen it both in commercial projects and in freeware/opensource ones.

So - yes, it's good and proven architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register functions manually. Really? Really.

What you could use is a proxy implementation for your plugin interface, where each function loads its original from the shared library on demand, transparently, and calls it. Whoever reaches a proxy object of that interface definition just can call the functions. They will be loaded on demand.

If plugins are singletons, then there is no need for manual binding at all (otherwise the correct instance has to be chosen first).

The idea for the developer of a new plugin would be to describe the interface first, then have a generator which generates a stub for the implementation for the shared library, and additionally a plugin proxy class with the same signature but with the autoloading on demand which then is used in the client software. Both should fulfill the same interface (in C++ a pure abstract class).