# template function typecasted to BinaryFunc

Tags: c++, opencv

BinaryFunc is defined in core.hpp as

```
typedef void (*BinaryFunc)(const uchar* src1, size_t step1,
                       const uchar* src2, size_t step2,
                       uchar* dst, size_t step, Size sz,
                       void*);
```

and `BinaryFunc getConvertFunc(int sdepth, int ddepth)` returns a template

```
template<typename T, typename DT> static void
cvt_( const T* src, size_t sstep, DT* dst, size_t dstep, Size size )
```

What is the point of having cvt_ as template if it's always typecasted as BinaryFunc? In case of cvt8u32f for example, `getConvertFunc` should return `cvt_<short, float>`. But because it is typecasted, wouldn't it return `cvt_<uchar, uchar>`?

Also, I tried to replicate the code in `convert.cpp` in the following manner :

```
template<typename TS, typename TD> static void
test_(TS src, TD dst) {
    dst = (TD)(src * dst);
    cout << src << " " << dst << " " << __func__ << endl;
}

#define GET_NAME(suffix, stype, dtype) \
    void test_##suffix(stype src, dtype dst) \
    {\
        test_(src, dst); \
    }

GET_NAME(32f32s, float, int)
GET_NAME(32f64f, float, double)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    typedef void (*func)(int, int);
    func f1 = (func)(&test_32f32s);
    func f2 = (func)(&test_32f64f);

    f1(2.4f, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I get `src = 0` in test_. Why is this happening?

if the function pointer is defined as

```
typedef void (*func)(float, int);
```

I get the desired result for f1.

**Edit 1:** If I call `test_32f32s(2.4f, 1)` then as well I get the desired result. But I tried to replicate the `BinaryFunc` syntax which isn't working.

**Edit 2:** Using a void* in typedef works somehow. Here's the code

```
template<typename TS, typename TD> static void
test_(TS *src, TD *dst) {
    *dst = (TD)(*(TS*)src * *(TD*)dst);
    cout << *src << " " << *dst << " " << __func__ << endl;
}

#define GET_NAME(suffix, stype, dtype) \
    void test_##suffix(stype *src, dtype *dst) \
    {\
    test_(src, dst); \
    }

GET_NAME(32f16s, float, int)
GET_NAME(32f64f, float, double)

typedef void (*func)(void*, void*);

func getFunc(int type) {
    func fns[] = {(func)(test_32f16s),
           (func)(test_32f64f)};

    return fns[type];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float tmpf = 10.0f; float *f = &tmpf;
    int tmpi = 2; int *i = &tmpi;
    double tmpd = 5.0; double *d = &tmpd;
    cout << *f << " " << *i << " " << *d << endl;

    func fnf = getFunc(0);
    fnf(f, i);
    func fnd = getFunc(1);
    fnd(f, d);
}
```

This is just to understand the style of coding used here.

Comment: `template<typename T, typename DT> static void
cvt_( const T* src, size_t sstep, DT* dst, size_t dstep, Size size )`  Where do you see this returning a template?  The return type is `void`.  Maybe the formatting (which I don't like) is throwing you off.

Comment: I didn't mean the return type of the function. I meant getConvertFunc returns a function of type BinaryFunc

Comment: When it comes to C-style casting, a lot can be revealed if you removed the cast and see what the compiler errors are.

Comment: `invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(float, int)’ to ‘func {aka void (*)(int, int)}`. But how are the function ptrs in convert.cpp typecasted?

Comment: Please see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238653/cast-a-function-pointer  That's why I asked to remove the C-style casts.  The error that the C++ compiler gives you becomes informative.  The compiler knows something smells...What the code is attempting to do is bypass the C++ type-safety.  Unless you know *exactly* what you're doing, why you're doing it, and the implications of doing so, "shutting up" the compiler by issuing a C-style cast should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: I am just trying to replicate `(BinaryFunc)GET_OPTIMIZED(cvt8u32f)` which I am unable to understand.

Comment: Why replicate something that is undefined behavior?  You can cast the pointer, but calling the function through that pointer is undefined behavior.  The link I posted in the comment discusses this.  As to your previous comment "how are the function ptrs in convert.cpp typecasted", you can cast basically anything to anything using a C-style casts.  You didn't get a syntax error when you did this, right?  And what were the results when you attempted to call the function?  See the link.